# Check if $_POST exists

Tags: php

I'm trying to check whether a $_POST exists and if it does, print it inside another string, if not, don't print at all.

something like this:

```
$fromPerson = '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];

function fromPerson() {
    if !($_POST['fromPerson']) {
        print ''
    } else {
        print $fromPerson
    };
}

$newString = fromPerson();
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 200, accepted):

```
if( isset($_POST['fromPerson']) )
{
     $fromPerson = '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];
     echo $fromPerson;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but didn't work, rather use `if($_POST['fromPerson'])`

Answer (score 74):

## Simple. You've two choices:

### 1. Check if there's ANY post data at all

```
//Note: This resolves as true even if all $_POST values are empty strings
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    // handle post data
    $fromPerson = '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];
    echo $fromPerson;
}
```

### (OR)

### 2. Only check if a PARTICULAR Key is available in post data

```
if (isset($_POST['fromPerson']) )
{
    $fromPerson = '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];
    echo $fromPerson;
}
```

Comment: As per Shi's comment [on Augustus Francis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578542/199364), `empty()` is **not** correct for choice #1, because in php, the string `'0'` is equivalent to `false` - and `empty()` returns `true` for *all values equivalent to false*. So using `empty`, the code would skip printing if the value was `'0'`. If you want to exclude the empty string, see Augustus answer.

Answer (score 39):

Surprised it has not been mentioned

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['fromPerson'])){
```

Comment: Why?  If server method isn't POST, then the POST variable won't be set, so the second half is all that is needed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes in most cases that is enough but not always my answer was to show another way it could be done.

Comment: It will also work if you have a form with checkboxes and submit without a name.

Comment: Describe a situation where `isset($_POST['fromPerson']` is `true`, even though `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` is `false`. Unless there is such a situation, all that is needed is the `isset...` part.

Comment: True, but it's the other way around. `fromPerson` might not be present, but POST might still exist. The question was, "If $_POST exists." and only in an example, $_POST['fromPerson'] is used. In some situations, as [@goat describes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit), even if `fromPerson` was a Submit name, it might not be present in POST.

Comment: there are definately situations where you wanna check for server request method, but this is more an api thing, or when you wanna check wheter f.e. PUT was requested on the server and then drop the request ( if you want to forbid PUT ) -> for this question, it is unneccesary

Answer (score 35):

Everyone is saying to use isset() - which will probably work for you.

However, it's important that you understand the difference between

`$_POST['x'] = NULL;` and `$_POST['x'] = '';`

`isset($_POST['x'])` will return `false` on the first example, but will return `true` on the second one even though if you tried to print either one, both would return a blank value.

If your `$_POST` is coming from a user-inputted field/form and is left blank, I BELIEVE (I am not 100% certain on this though) that the value will be "" but NOT NULL.

Even if that assumption is incorrect (someone please correct me if I'm wrong!) the above is still good to know for future use.

Comment: empty() checks for variable existence and a non-empty value, so that's the function to use when an empty string should return false.

Comment: @HanDijk - as per Shi's comment [on Augustus Francis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578542/199364), `empty()` is **not** correct here, because in php, the string `'0'` is equivalent to `false` - and `empty()` returns `true` for *all values equivalent to false*. So using `empty`, the code would skip printing if the value was `'0'`.

Comment: imho it's always better to write a class that would acceppt all POST data and then check inside that class. you might try to strlen on each post field and catch the exception that would result when testing against NULL, and when strlen is actually 0, it's probably because the param was ""

Answer (score 22):

```
isset($_POST['fromPerson'])
```

Answer (score 17):

The proper way of checking if array key exists is function `array_key_exists()`

The difference is that when you have `$_POST['variable'] = null` it means that key exists and was send but value was null

The other option is `isset()` which which will check if array key exists and if it was set

The last option is to use `empty()` which will check if array key exists if is set and if value is not considered empty.

Examples:

```
$arr = [
  'a' => null,
  'b' => '',
  'c' => 1
];

array_key_exists('a', $arr); // true
isset($arr['a']); // false
empty($arr['a']); // true


array_key_exists('b', $arr); // true
isset($arr['b']); // true
empty($arr['b']); // true


array_key_exists('c', $arr); // true
isset($arr['c']); // true
empty($arr['c']); // false
```

Regarding your question

The proper way to check if value was send is to use array_key_exists() with check of request method

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && array_key_exists('fromPerson', $_POST)    
{
   // logic
}
```

But there are some cases depends on your logic where `isset()` and `empty()` can be good as well.

Comment: Fantastic answer, except for the suggestion to use `empty`. As per Shi's comment [on Augustus Francis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578542/199364), `empty()` is **not** correct as an alternative choice, because in php, the string `'0'` is equivalent to `false` - and `empty()` returns `true` for *all values equivalent to false*. So using `empty`, the code would skip printing if the value was `'0'`. If you want to exclude the empty string, see Augustus answer.

Answer (score 9):

- In that case using method `isset` is not appropriate.

According to PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
(see Example #2  *array_key_exists() vs isset()*)
The method `array_key_exists` is intended for checking key presence in array.

So code in the question could be changed as follow:

```
function fromPerson() {
   if (array_key_exists('fromPerson', $_POST) == FALSE) {
        return '';
   } else {
        return '+from%3A'.$_POST['fromPerson'];
   };
}

$newString = fromPerson();
```

- Checking presence of array $_POST is not necessary because it is PHP environment global variable since version 4.1.0 (nowadays we does not meet older versions of PHP).

Comment: This code only differs in behavior from the `isset` solution when the post field is set but contains NULL. This is a *good alternative*, *if* you want to allow `NULL` in the `else` branch. *However*, it is a mistake, if a string is needed; in that situation `isset` does the right thing, but this code does not - it will pass the `NULL` value on. [Robert's later answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36599270/199364) demonstrates the difference.

Answer (score 7):

All the methods are actually discouraged, it's a warning in Netbeans 7.4 and it surely is a good practice not to access superglobal variables directly, use a ***[filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)*** instead

```
$fromPerson = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fromPerson', FILTER_DEFAULT);
if($fromPerson === NULL) { /*$fromPerson is not present*/ }
else{ /*present*/ }
var_dump($fromPerson);exit(0);
```

Comment: On the other hand, READABILITY of code is also important. IMHO, `isset` is a lot more readable than a filter expression. But thank you for pointing this out; it is a useful option to consider.

Comment: well, you can write your own myIsset/2 wrapper metod that uses filters but has the behaviour of isset/2

Comment: "All the methods are actually discouraged" - that's a strong statement (even if NetBeans does mark as a warning). Do you have a link to an *authoritative source*, that *discourages* direct references to $_POST? (There is a *lot* about php that is designed for coding convenience rather than rigor - look at how many people in the answers to this question incorrectly use `empty`, tripped up by php's loose typing; its hard to imagine that accessing $_POST would be considered poor style.)

Comment: if you only need to know if it exists but you don't care about the value, for example, to check a submit button, you can use `filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'fromPerson')`.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
if (isset($_POST['fromPerson']) && $_POST['fromPerson'] != "") {
    echo "Cool";
}
```

Comment: Per Han Dijk's comment on Rafael's answer, `empty($_POST['fromPerson'])` does this combined test. Easier to read and to type :)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: `empty('0')` returns `true`. So it's not the same.

Comment: @Shi - yes, you are correct; what I said is wrong! It seems there is no simpler solution than the code shown here.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add my answer even though this thread is years old and it ranked high in Google for me.

My best method is to try:

```
if(sizeof($_POST) !== 0){
// Code...
}
```

As `$_POST` is an array, if the script loads and no data is present in the `$_POST` variable it will have an array length of 0. This can be used in an IF statement.

You may also be wondering if this throws an "undefined index" error seeing as though we're checking if `$_POST` is set... In fact `$_POST` always exists, the "undefined index" error will only appear if you try to search for a $_POST array value that doesn't exist.

`$_POST` always exists in itself being either empty or has array values.
`$_POST['value']` may not exist, thus throwing an "undefined index" error.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset)`($_POST['fromPerson'])`?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (is_array($_POST) && array_key_exists('fromPerson', $_POST)) {
    echo 'blah' . $_POST['fromPerson'];
}
```

Comment: Does is_array($_POST) check if there are any values at all in POST? In my app I'm trying to determine if there was a post or not before doing anything else.

Comment: See my edit. `is_array()` checks whether it's an array, the second part checks whether it has an item with the key `'fromPerson'`.

Answer (score 2):

`if( isset($_POST['fromPerson']) )` is right.

You can use a function and return, better then directing echo.

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the discussion, that wasn't already said in other answers, *years* earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I like to check if it isset and if it's empty in a ternary operator.

```
// POST variable check
$userID  = (isset( $_POST['userID'] )    && !empty( $_POST['userID'] ))   ? $_POST['userID']   :  null;
$line    = (isset( $_POST['line'] )      && !empty( $_POST['line'] ))     ? $_POST['line']     :  null;
$message = (isset( $_POST['message'] )   && !empty( $_POST['message'] ))  ? $_POST['message']  :  null;
$source  = (isset( $_POST['source'] )    && !empty( $_POST['source'] ))   ? $_POST['source']   :  null;
$version = (isset( $_POST['version'] )   && !empty( $_POST['version'] ))  ? $_POST['version']  :  null;
$release = (isset( $_POST['release'] )   && !empty( $_POST['release'] ))  ? $_POST['release']  :  null;
```

Comment: `empty('0')` is `true`. So better not have `version` `0`, or `userID` `0`, etc.

Answer (score -3):

I recently came up with this:

```
class ParameterFetcher
{
public function fetchDate(string $pDate):string{
    $myVar = "";
    try{
        if(strlen($_POST[$pDate]) > 0){
            $myVar = $_POST[$pDate];
        }
    }catch (Exception $faild){
        die("field NULL or not set for $pDate");
    }

    [ ... other stuff ]
```

to fetch a date obviously, but it can take ANY post param. You can also check for GET this way.

Comment: Why is this a class? Why are you unsafely accessing an array index without `isset` check? Why would this raise an exception? Why are you testing `$_POST` but are getting `$_GET`? Why are you `die`ing when catching the exception? This is like… all the worst possible practices rolled into one short snippet.

Comment: i already corrected the mistake. was posting an old version lol and the die("text") is just for debugging here. replace it with a return or standart value (or an exception object)

Comment: That still leaves a lot of unaddressed criticism…

Comment: let me try and answere them: this is a class to keep hexagonal architecture and have a class whose domain is parsing of POST. i am unsafely accessing a post field with strlen to both check wheter it's set and if it holds a value. isset will just do about the same internally i guess

Comment: But this will produce a notice and/or warning, which is what `isset` is there to prevent…

Comment: it is? i don't get any notice / warning. i have reporting turned on and looking through the symfony logs. only phpstorm tells me i should use `if($_POST[$pDate] !== '')` ... i'm sorry if i committed taboo by reimplementing isset here