# Checking if $_POST variable is populated

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if $_POST exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists)

I'm trying to run something if and only if a $_POST var is populated.

Can I do `if(empty($_POST[...])) { ... }`? Or should I go about this another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "populated"? If `$_POST['key']` contains an empty string, is it populated or not?

Comment: i would use if(isset($_POST['uid']) && isset($_POST['authtoken']) && !empty($_POST['uid'])&& !empty($_POST['authtoken'])){   }

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd do `if(isset($_POST['key'])) { ... }`

Comment: if $_POST['key'] is present without a value it returns true which is not always what you want.

Answer (score 4):

No, empty() is not the right way of doing it. You have to use isset().

Why? Because many things are considered empty which you probably don't want to miss!

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

[See the manual!](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php)

Comment: Only the string type can be present in the input arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` wether it is `POST` or something else. See [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Ooops, I totally misread your question. Do you want to test for a *specific* entry in `$_POST`? Then use `array_key_exists($key, $_POST)`.

Comment: Perfect for use inside a loop! :)