# Which empty form fields get set in $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms

After submitting an HTML form, I noticed that SOME empty input fields get sent to the $_POST array while others don't (they all have a name attribute). What determines what gets set and what does not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>EXAMPLE TEST</title></head>
<body>

<form action="/test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
  <input type="date" name="date">
  <textarea name="textarea" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

  <!-- etc... -->
</form>

<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Leaving all fields untouched and submitting the form, var_dump($_POST) shows:

`array(3) { ["text"]=> string(0) "" ["textarea"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

I'm asking this because my script "was" seemingly adding the empty radio to $_POST["radio"] and my script was working fine, but now suddenly it doesn't appear in the array. I haven't modified anything in my script. But my question isn't about my script, my question is: how do I know which empty fields get set in the $_POST array, and is this always guaranteed?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php ?

Comment: your radio and checkbox is missng value attributes. This determines if `isset()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if $\_POST exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists)

Comment: adding values doesn't change anything btw

Comment: Radio button and Checkboxes only get sent if they contain a positive piece of information i.e. they are ticked or checked. Text is always sent even if empty, Buttons will be sent when they are pressed, i.e. if you have 2 buttons only the one that is pressed is sent so you can tell which one it was the user pressed. You should always check for the existance of fields in the $_POST/$_GET arrays before using them, using `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` whichever suits the situation and your own preferences

Comment: @Anonymous no no, not check if the key exists. But know what gets sent to the $_POST array when submitting the form.

Comment: If you know what you want to be sent, it would be the same result.  Obviously, the former could be done, but it seems rather frivolous.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't think you read my question carefully, either that or my English wasn't good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Checkboxes and radio buttons will only be sent if they are checked.
- Text inputs will always be sent ([as long as they are not disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8925716/362536)), but will be empty strings if not filled in.
- Submit buttons will be sent if they are clicked.

The browser and the standards determine this.  It has nothing to do with PHP specifically.