# Check whether POST array is empty

Tags: php, arrays, post, conditional-statements

I am checking $_POST arrays, but I cannot find a way to check whether the array is empty. Does anyone know how I can check this. I have tried `!empty()` and `isset()`, but both ways returning true.

**My HTML form with a select box, text field and submit button:**

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="product_name[]">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
    <input name="product_price[]" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**My PHP:**

```
if( ! empty( $_POST['product_name'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['product_price'] ) ) {

    print_r( $_POST['product_name'] );
    print_r( $_POST['product_price'] );
}
```

**Return:**

```
Array ( [0] => Camera ) 
Array ( [0] => )
```

Comment: if you post an empty value it counts as an array value

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists

Comment: try `sizeof($array)>0` to determine if array values more than 0

Comment: Is it necessary to have `[]` after your input names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an array so you need to use `array_filter` to get rid of empty strings.

```
if(!empty($_POST['product_name']) && array_filter($_POST['product_price'])){    
    print_r( $_POST['product_name']);
    print_r( $_POST['product_price']);
}
```

**[*Check here.*](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BxQIy8)**

Comment: Please don't use `empty(array_filter())`, just `array_filter` will do just fine. In fact, your code throws errors in PHP < 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should just add default first option as empty string? And don't name inputs like `product_name[]`. Change it to `product_name`.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="product_name">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
        <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
        <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
    <input name="product_price" type="text" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

If that first option will be chosen, [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function should return `TRUE`.

Comment: if you change the statement of the select from `product_name[]` to `product_name` it will not return an array anymore

Comment: And for what You need `input` type `text` as array? And... if You need `select` to have multiple values, You just simply add `multiple` attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared product_name[](hence array empty will return `TRUE` if option 1 is selected) you would have to change it to product_name

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="product_name">
      <option value="">-</option>
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
    <input name="product_price" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I found the solution. Previous answer was wrong hope this will help you:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="product_name[]">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Radio">Radio</option>
      <option value="Television">Television</option>
    </select>
    <input name="product_price[]" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form> 

<?php

if( !empty( $_POST['product_name'] ) && !count( array_filter($_POST['product_price'])) ==0 ) {

    print_r( $_POST['product_name'] );
    print_r( $_POST['product_price'] );
}
?>
```

Comment: @Unskilled Not if the array is "empty", i.e. `array()`.

Comment: @Robbert Please check and let me know is it correct and resolve your problem.

Comment: Anybody who doing down vote first check the code and then vote down. As i have run this code and it is working.