# Php fails to open stream even with permissions, restrictions and filesize checked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server

I'm trying to make php save data on the server. Those data are generated through js script. However, I am unable to make the php create the file. The error msg I get is as follows: Warning: file_put_contents(data/) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in

I have checked the permissions and the php.ini for restrictions with zero success. Any ideas?

If I change the "data/" bit to "X", the server creates an empty file named X. Which seems strange. The commands used in the js script come from jsPsych.

Thanks a lot!

I append the code:

```
function saveData(name, data){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('POST', 'write_data.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({filename: name, filedata: data}));
};
```

(...)

on_finish:

```
function(){
  saveData('subject-'+subject_id+'.csv', jsPsych.data.get().csv() );
}

<?php

$filename = 'data/'.$_POST['filename'];
$data = $_POST['filedata'];
file_put_contents($filename, $data);

?>
```

Comment: The php got lost somehow:<?php

$filename = 'data/'.$_POST['filename'];

$data = $_POST['filedata'];

file_put_contents($filename, $data);

?>

Comment: Please edit your post to add the php

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the edit button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert with Xhr & your style of doing it. I do however know jQuery, and regular JS.

Jquery method:

```
var postName = 'something'; // this is found with $_POST['postName'] in PHP
var postName2 = 'somethingElse'; 
$.post("path/yourFile.php", {postName:value, postName2:value}, function(data){
            if(data == 'success'){
                // complete success 
            } else {
                // assessment failed to save
                console.log(data); 
            }
        });
```

JS Methods:

The first thing you do, is open up your request...

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", "write_data.php", true);
```

Try this...

> xhr.open("POST", "write_data.php", **true**);

Then you can either use this way of doing it...

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Wubur&lname=Com");
```

Or the JSON way...

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({fname:"Harry", lname:"Potter"}));
```

yourFile.php (where we are POSTing to):

*If you use the first method (NOT json)...*

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']){ // check for post param & permission to create template 
    // do stuff here... 
    echo 'success'; // if everything worked
} else {
    echo 'I need fname and lname!!!'; // no post params supplied 
}

?>
```

*If you use JSON method...*

```
<?php 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$data2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
// try both, I forget which one it is...
echo "success";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the structure as follows: .php is in a directory with the .html with the AJAX call and in that directory there is the "data" file where the .csv is supposed to go to.  So if I got the gist of your response, I feel like the structure is set up properly. Am I right?

Comment: I tried to change the content-type too and it didn't work :(

Comment: You need to change the content type AND get rid of JSON stringify. On PHP do echo $_POST['filename']

Comment: Like this?   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send({filename: name, filedata: data});

Comment: I updated my answer. It has all the options. I believe you will be able to figure it out :)

Comment: You are my favourite person, thanks, will hop on it immediately.

Comment: Ok, I did it and we definitely moved forward for which I thank you dearly :) The .php console now correctly shows the data. Only trouble now is that the file created does not have a correct name. Here's the code (I intentionally made it save to the same folder as the php to avoid trouble with the data dir): <?php 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$filename = 'X'.$_POST['filename'];
file_put_contents($filename, $data);

echo "success";
print_r($data);

?>

Comment: And I should add that printing both the "filename" and "data" shows exactly what it should. It's just that the file isn't ACTUALLY being named correctly, plus it appears some time after executing.

Comment: It's working :) I didn't realize I should change the other part too.

Comment: Oh awesome! Well if it helped you make sure u mark as answer(: also, I used to use same method as you. I highly recommend using jQuery $.post and $.get. a lot easier, also a lot of great options to use

Comment: Yeah, thanks for everything, I'll check the jQuery way for sure!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `$_POST['filename'];` is empty. The error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(data/) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Is a directory

Is self explanatory and even shows `data/`. Notice the lack of file name after the "/"? Check your incoming post.

**More Details**

The Super Global `$_POST` does not have a key `filename` or that key is empty.  This line of code `$filename = 'data/'.$_POST['filename'];` produces this: `data/`. So either `$_POST['filename']` is empty or it does not exist. Use `var_dump` or `print_r` to examine `$_POST` and see what's in it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I checked the console and it shows in "request payload" that the filedata as well as the filename is being sent correctly.

Comment: Check your `$_POST` data in **PHP**. The error clearly shows "data/" which is indeed a directory and not a file name.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm a bit clueless on what do you mean. I suppose there is something essential eluding me. I tried something along these lines, but am still getting the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496971/check-if-post-exists

Comment: Try something like `print_r($_POST)` to see the exact structure of your data as it is being received by PHP.

Comment: Thank you :). It showed an empty array (Array ( ) ).

Comment: Right it's not showing  up from your ajax call. And that is the problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm finally moving towards the solution, I hope. I have checked the AJAX code a few times but can't seem to find anything wrong, though. I'm sorry to be a bother but do you have any ideas for what to look? I don't see any typos or anything strange.

Comment: @PetrPalíšek The content type of the ajax request is preventing the data from populating the super global array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822905/php-fails-to-open-stream-even-with-permissions-restrictions-and-filesize-checke/49823545#answer-49823545

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be based around your content type. In PHP, only a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`or `multipart/form-data` populates the `$_POST` super global array. Since you are telling the server that you are sending the data via `application/json`, you need to fetch the data from the request body via:

`php://input`

Try this:

```
$params = json_decode("php://input", TRUE);
$filename = 'data/'.$params['filename'];
$data = $params['filedata'];
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the code but it didn't change anything (same error and the array is still empty)

Comment: As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php if you need more info OP

Comment: @PetrPalíšek Interesting. I haven't encountered that before. Are you able to verify that the data is posting correctly? Try reviewing the request payload in your browsers dev tools, typically under the _Network_ tab. You should see a request labeled: `xhr` with the content type that you set and the data being passed to this server.

Comment: Yep, that's what is puzzling me. The request payload shows exactly what it should.

Comment: Your code has helped me too after all :) I just didn't realize how to mirror it in the Js. Thanks!