# Is It possible to have two submit buttons in one form with differents redirects in contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Wordpress (Contact form 7)

I have one submit button know, that has a redirect to a page:
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/?page_id=1';"

Know I wanna know if its possible to have one more submit button in the same form redirecting to another page?

Or Is It possible to do it without using on_sent_ok:?

Comment: You got only 1 action in form in pure html.. But you can make a page where you will be handling your form depending on submit button clicked. Or you can use javascript.

Comment: @ailvenge Ok, thanks. Do you know any examples out there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you have to [name your button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_name.asp) and add a value to it. That will be sent with the form. On the server you can check what button was pressed by checking which button name (and value) is present in the request parameters.

For example:

HTML on the client:

```
<form action="auth.php" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password - at least 5 characters</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br />
    <button name="subject" type="submit" value="register">Sign up</button>
    <button name="subject" type="submit" value="login">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

PHP on the server

```
if ($_POST['subject'] == 'register') {
    //register user
    header('location: registered.php');
}
else if ($_POST['subject'] == 'login') {
    //login user
    header('location: profile.php');
}
```

*note:

If you want to send the same form using completely different actions, then you have to use javascript `onsubmit` or a non-submit button with `onclick` to change the form action, or send the data with AJAX.*