# How to handle two submit buttons in my form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create two submit button in my form

```
<form id="form-input-wrapper" action='test.php'>

//form items..
//form items..

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="old">first button.</button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="new">second button</button>
</form>
```

My question is how to distinquish which button the user clicks in my `test.php` page?

Comment: Give the buttons a name and check if they are set and/or have values after submit

Comment: I think you want the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `name` attribute to your buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="old" value="old">first button.</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="new" value="new">second button</button>
```

The php code to use would look like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //something posted

    if (isset($_POST['old'])) {
        //old
    } elseif (isset($_POST['new']){
        //new
    }
}
```

related question: 
[How can I tell which button was clicked in a PHP form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit)

Answer (score 1):

Use button name tag and check them in php:

```
<button name="subject1" type="submit" value="HTML">HTML</button>
<button name="subject2" type="submit" value="CSS">CSS</button>
```

And in php:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     if ( isset($_POST['subject1']) )   {
       // first button is clicked

     } elseif ( isset($_POST['subject2']) )   {
        //second button is clicked

     }
  }
?>
```