# isset condition for different submit button

Tags: php, html

I have two submit button in my webpage.
Once a button is clicked (using post method), it will do perform different action.

How do I check which of the two button is clicked by the user?

The code for the two button

```
<form name="existingForm" method="post" action="">
     <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="text-align: center;">
          <label>Are you a returning customer?</label>
          <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Login Here" />
     </div>
</form>

<form name="logingForm" method="post" action="">
     <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="text-align: center;">
          <label>Are you a returning customer?</label>
          <input name="button2" type="submit" value="Login Here" />
     </div>
</form>
```

The code for post method for button 1:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $buttonPressed = 1;
    }
```

The code for post method for button 2:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $buttonPressed -= 1;
    }
```

Comment: You have two identical form

Comment: I have edited the form

Comment: `isset($_POST['button1'])` / `isset($_POST['button2'])`

Comment: may be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check if the respective `button` is pressed or not and then do your stuff? Something like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button1']))
{
// your stuff for existingForm
}
else 
if(isset($_POST['button2']))
{
// your stuff for logingForm
}

<form name="existingForm" method="post" action="">
     <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="text-align: center;">
          <label>Are you a returning customer?</label>
          <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Login Here" />
     </div>
</form>

<form name="logingForm" method="post" action="">
     <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="text-align: center;">
          <label>Are you a returning customer?</label>
          <input name="button2" type="submit" value="Login Here" />
     </div>
</form>
```