# Submit button not in request bag

Tags: php, forms, laravel, post

I have a form with buttons "Accept" and "Decline". When I submit form I'd like to see if order was accepted or declined. I know how it should be done, but for some reason it wasn't not working.

**FORM:**

```
<form action="{{ url('edi')}}/lv/{{ $customer->name }}" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="{{ $edifile }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="doctype" value="order">
    <select name="ordertype" class="form-control">
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="accept" value="Accept order">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="decline" value="Decline order" onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to DECLINE this order!');">
</form>
```

**Request parameter bag:**

```
+request: ParameterBag {#41 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "_token" => "bW5ancRgkgvFovCeQuVxzOiXIu75ng6zl5NYlEyc"
      "file" => "ORDER_20170706122126714_P2576090-1.xml"
      "doctype" => "order"
      "ordertype" => "0"
    ]
  }
```

As you see there is no submit button name in request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While I was writing this question I found problem myself:**

Basically problem was that when ever form is submitted we have a script that disables all submit buttons in form so user can't submit same form twice. All sounds fine until we understand - disabled elements aren't submitted"

**Solution:**

I changed script so that it would create input type="hidden" with name of originally pressed button.

P.S.
Accepted answer has a good "rule of thumb" in it and I have read it and you you should too if you haven't already: [How can I tell which button was clicked in a PHP form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)