# Which Submit Button was Clicked in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

### Which Submit Button was Clicked in CakePHP?

** what is solution for 2 buttons on same form with only 1 action in cakephp? **

> ```
>           i have following code,1 form contain 2 buttons print & ship,if i click 
>    print  button,page is redirected on printorder page but problem is , if i click ship
>    button it is not working & page is redirected on printorder.
> ```

```
      ========================================================================== 


     <?php // in index.ctp file

    echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'orders','type' =>'post'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Ship',array('name'=>'user','value'=>'Ship','id'=>'1'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Print',array('name'=>'user','value'=>'Print','id'=>'2'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>

      <?php // in UserController
          public function orders() 
              {
            if($this->params->data['form']['user'] = "Print" )
             {
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'printorder'));
             }
            if($this->params->data['form']['user'] = "Ship")
            {
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'shiporder')); 
             }
            }


       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have created one form and you are submitting 2 different values on the "USER" form.

so it will redirected because action of the form is common.

To avoid it.. Using of 2 different forms are the best way.

Another way is to use javascript but I suggest to use 2 different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Typical solution to [two submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942772/html-form-with-two-submit-buttons-and-two-target-attributes) situation is to create a submit button (default action) and a regular button to handle another action. Than you can use the JavaScript to implement the behaviour of the second button, e.g. to set a value of a hidden field which contains the actual 'action' string:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'orders','type' =>'post'));
echo $this->Form->hidden('submit_action', array(id='submit_action')); ?>
echo $this->Form->submit('Ship',array('value'=>'Ship','id'=>'ship_button'));
echo $this->Form->button('Print',array('value'=>'Print','id'=>'print_button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

And the js:

```
<script>
var form = <get your form here>
var print_button = document.getElementById('print_button');
print_button.onclick = function() {
    // Set value of print button to the #submit_action hidden field
     document.getElementById('submit_action').value = print_button.value; 
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the top voted (not selected solution) from [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form), which suggested applying different values to each submit button, and checking those on submit.

However, CakePHP didn't easily play with this technique, as despite setting `'value'` key in the `$options` array of `$this->Form->submit`, no value was set on the generated element. So, I followed the suggestions from [here](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/getting-name-submit-button-clicked-after-post-cakephp/), and used the `'name'` value key.

**view.ctp**

```
    $this->Form->submit('Submit 1', array('name' => 'action1'));
    $this->Form->submit('Submit 2', array('name' => 'anotherAction'));
```

**controller.php**

```
    if (array_key_exists('action1', $this->request->data)) {
        /** setup any data you want to retain after redirect 
          *  in Session, Model, or add to redirect URL below
          */
        // redirect to another action
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'myOtherAction'));
    } else if (array_key_exists('anotherAction', $this->request->data)) {
        // do something with anotherAction submit         
    }
```