# One form, two buttons?

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have a form. I want it to have two buttons (buttonA, buttonB). Is there a better way to figure out which button was clicked than keeping a hidden input field, and setting its value via javascript in onClick() to a different string for each?

This is what this article is demonstrating:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/JspformUsingButtons.htm

But it seems a little weird, is there no better way than jumping through those hoops?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML form with two submit buttons and two "target" attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942772/html-form-with-two-submit-buttons-and-two-target-attributes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `name` and `value` attributes to differentiate the buttons on the form, then read the appropriate value from the server.  Here is an example:

```
​<form method="get" action="test.htm" target="new">
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="1">Button One</button>
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="2">Button Two</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

When `Button 1` is clicked, the URL will contain `button=1`, and of course when `Button 2` is clicked, `button=2`.

Obviously, you can use any `name` property you wish, as long as both buttons have the same `name`.  This will work the same using `POST` instead of `GET`.

http://jsfiddle.net/M74xN/

Answer (score 2):

with jsp and servlets the possible operation will be:

in the html or jsp page

​

```
<form method="POST" action="servlet">
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="add">add</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="edit">delete</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Servlet POST method**

```
if (request.getParameter("action") != null) //if action is not null
        {
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
            if (action.equals("add")) //add button clicked
            {
               //do your work here
            }
            else if (action.equals("edit")) //delete button clicked
            {
                //your work here
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a form, set different values of submit button, and have your script perform different actions depending on what button is pressed.

```
if (isset($_POST) {
    if ($_POST['button'] == 1) {
     /* BUTTON ONE PRESSED, INSERT PROCESSING HERE*/
    } else if ($_POST['button'] == 2) {
     /* BUTTON TWO PRESSED, INSERT PROCESSING HERE*/
    } else {
     /* NO BUTTON PRESSED, (THIS ELSE STATEMENT MAY NOT BE NEEDED) */
    }

/** END OF PHP CODE **/
<--! start of html -->
<html>
<form method="get" action="<?php echo "$server['php_self']; ?>" target="new">
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="1">Button One</button>
  <button type="submit" name="button" value="2">Button Two</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer might be late. This works perfectly. Use the following in your HTML.

```
<form action="/route" method="POST">
    <button name="submit" value="ONE">
    <button name="submit" value="TWO">
</form>
```

Then in your Python(Flask) use this

```
if request.form['submit'] == 'ONE':
    print('button one clicked')
elif request.form['submit'] == 'TWO':
    print('button two clicked')
```