# Debugging two buttons for one form

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116052/one-form-two-buttons) and [this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form/21778226#21778226), but the solution of using the `<button>` tag has not worked for me.

I think it's because I'm using `FormData`, but I thought that `FormData` would pick up on all the submitted keys and values.

Here's a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhf5b8rL/1/) for what I'm trying to do, but it's not working. I expect to see the `first` and `second` values show up in the FormData object, but only the `input-data` shows up.

**I need to be able to determine which button was pressed to submit the form.**

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // don't have the browser refresh on submit
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ' ==> ' + pair[1]);
    }
}

const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
  <form id="form">
    <input name="input-data"/>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="first">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="second">Another Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What is your question? Your JSFiddle works fine for me.

Comment: Question has been edited to explain what I expected

Comment: For more information about what's going on and other ways to fix it, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277900/formdata-object-does-not-add-submit-type-inputs-from-form-while-on-firefox

Comment: And what about if the form is directly submited by  keys  `Crtl` + `Enter`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **FormData not collect value of buttons. You can set value for a hidden input like this:**

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // don't have the browser refresh on submit

    document.getElementById('action').value = event.submitter.value;

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ' ==> ' + pair[1]);
    }
}

const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="input-data"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value=""/>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="first">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="second">Another Submit</button>
</form>
```

> **Cross Browser Solution**

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("input-data", document.getElementById("input-data").value)
  formData.append(event.name, event.value);

  for (var entry of formData) {
      console.log(entry[0] + ' => ' + entry[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input-data"/>
  <button type="button" name="action" value="first" onclick="handleSubmit(this)">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" name="action2" value="second" onclick="handleSubmit(this)">Another Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: event.submitter  is Chrome and Android only  => https://caniuse.com/#search=submitter

Comment: @Pro Q, this solution works only browsers above. You can collect your values manually for cross browser solution.

Comment: I added a snippet for it

Comment: @ProQ none of these solutions will work if the form is submitted programmatically

Comment: @MisterJojo How can we know which button clicked while submitting programmatically? But if you want to know, this will work: `handleSubmit({ name: "input-data", value: "programmatically" })`

Comment: no i mean https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: We can also submit a form with keys  `Crtl` + `Enter`  and both of  your solutions won't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done using the FormData,

you have to code it yourself, something like that:

```js
const MyForm = document.getElementById('my-form')

var lastClick = null

MyForm.onclick=evt=>
  {
  lastClick = evt.target.matches('button[type=submit]') 
               ? evt.target.name 
               : null
  }

MyForm.onsubmit=evt=>
  {
  evt.preventDefault()
  console.clear()
  console.log ( 'submit by', lastClick) 
  let formData = new FormData(MyForm);
  for (let pair of formData.entries())
    {
    console.log(pair[0],' ==> ',pair[1])
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
    <input name="input-data"/>
    <button type="submit" name="first">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="second">Another Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: How can I be certain that no clicks will occur between the submission of the form and the processing of the form? In other words, what happens if a click that's not on the form occurs right after the `console.clear()` line? Will it log `submit by [null]`?

Comment: @ProQ The second solution of ibrahimyilmaz (which he added after mine) is 100% equivalent