# Submit function to both parent window and iframe from parent window form

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit, form-submit

I i have an iframe in a page and I want to be able to submit value to both the parent window and the iframe at the same time.

the form on the parent window is

```
<form name="ptform" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="javascript:handleSubmit();">
   <input class="zipcode" type="text" size="35" id="location" value="">
   <input class="method" type="hidden" id="method">
    <input class="search" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

and the form on the iframe is

```
    <form action="/embed/" method="get" onsubmit="return geocode()">
        <div id="addrWrap">
            <input type="text" id="addr" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchWrap">
            <input type="button" id="search" value="o" alt='Search' title='Search' onclick="geocode()" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

How do I combine the form to submit to both the parent window and the iframe at the same time?

Comment: this should do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942772/html-form-with-two-submit-buttons-and-two-target-attributes

Answer (score -2):

You can use HTML5 postMessage to achieve this.

http://html5demos.com/postmessage2

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Please post relevant code in answer, not just a link to the code.