# Spring <form:form> two action and two submit types for one form

Tags: html, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, tags

I have form:

```
<form:form id="searchForm" modelAttribute="fbosAttributes" action="result" method="get">

....

</form:form>
```

Inside of this form I have two submit buttons with name:

```
<input type="submit" name="ashtml" value="${labelbuttonhtml}"/>
<input type="submit" name="asexcel" value="${labelbuttonxls}"/>
```

Those two buttons works fine for different method in my controller, I use `params` to recognize:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result.xls", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="asexcel")
```

The question is how to make this to buttons react on different action and also how to add two actions inside of form?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript functions to post your form. You can call two different javascript functions onClick of buttons and you may submit your form from that function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript and any at all.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942772/html-form-with-two-submit-buttons-and-two-target-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Jquery,

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id = "ashtml" name="ashtml" value="${labelbuttonhtml}"/>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ashtml").click(function(){
         document.searchForm.action = "<%= request.getContextPath()/ashtml.htm %>"; 
      });
});
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ashtml.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript and any at all