# Play Framework 2.4: Getting the id of a button

Tags: java, playframework

I have the following form with repeating items:

```
 @(adverts: List[models.AdvertModel])
 @if(adverts.size() > 0 && adverts != null) {
    @helper.form(action = routes.UserController.editAdvert()) {
        @for( (advert, index) <- adverts zip (Stream from 0)) {
            <div>@adverts.get(index).title</div>
            <button type="submit" name="delete" id="delete_@index">delete</button>    

        }
     }
```

and this controller:

```
    public Result editAdvert() {
    String[] indices =   request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("delete");
    if (indices != null) {
        // delete advert
        }
    return ok();
}
```

I would like to be able to delete adverts according to their ids but with the current code my array contains a String `"delete"` instead of i.e.  `"delete_0"`.
How do I get the index of the clicked button?

Comment: I don't know Play forms well (I try to avoid html forms), but adding HTTP messages to the question might help. Usually I get them using my browser devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it:

**tldr:**

add `value="delete_@index"` to the button.

**longer answer:**

The value returned by `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("delete")`
is saved in the `value` attribute of the button with `name="delete"` in the scala template.
Therefore, by adding a `value="delete_@index"` to the button, we will get a String such as `delete_0`.

As @danielnixon commented, this is not a play-specific behaviour, but simply how html forms work.

Comment: Nothing Play Framework specific here. This is just how HTML forms work. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2129364/2476884