# Django redirect to previous page not working

Tags: html, django, redirect

Hi I want to redirect to the previous after submitting the form in django. It is successfully redirecting to the previous page but the post action is not happening. I am able to successfully post the data if I remove the action attribute.

This is my form template.

```
{% extends 'musicapp/base.html' %} {% block content %}
<!-- <h1>New post</h1> -->
<form method="POST" action={{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }} class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}



<div class="add_track_form" >

  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <section class="panel panel-default">
          <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Add Genre</header>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="{% url 'post_list' %}" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <label>Title</label>
                       {{ form.name }}
                  </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
      </section>
  </div>

</div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import AddTrackForm, AddGenreForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Track, Genre
from . import getAlbumArt

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    tracks = Track.objects.all().order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'musicapp/post_list.html', {'tracks': tracks})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    track = get_object_or_404(Track, pk=pk)
    # print post
    return render(request, 'musicapp/post_detail.html', {'track': track})
# def post_new(request):
#     form = AddTrackForm()
#     return render(request, 'musicapp/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddTrackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            artist = request.POST.get("artist", "")
            album = request.POST.get("album", "")
            # print artist, album
            urlArt = getAlbumArt.getAlbumArtURL(album, artist)
            print urlArt
            if urlArt:
                post.cover_image_url = urlArt
            if post.album == '*':
                post.album = 'Unknown'
            post.save()
            tracks = Track.objects.all().order_by('created_date')
            return render(request, 'musicapp/post_list.html', {'tracks': tracks})
    else:
        form = AddTrackForm()
    return render(request, 'musicapp/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Track, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddTrackForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            artist = request.POST.get("artist", "")
            album = request.POST.get("album", "")
            # print artist, album
            urlArt = getAlbumArt.getAlbumArtURL(album, artist)
            print urlArt
            if urlArt:
                post.cover_image_url = urlArt
            if post.album == '*':
                post.album = 'Unknown'
            post.save()
            tracks = Track.objects.all().order_by('created_date')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = AddTrackForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'musicapp/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def genre(request):
    tracks = Track.objects.all().order_by('created_date')
    genres = Genre.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'musicapp/genre.html', {'genres': genres, 'tracks': tracks})

def genre_songs(request, pk):
    genres = Genre.objects.all()
    genre_obj = get_object_or_404(Genre, pk=pk)
    tracks = genre_obj.track_set.all()
    # print post
    return render(request, 'musicapp/genre_songs.html', {'genres': genres, 'genre' : genre_obj, 'tracks': tracks})

def genre_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddGenreForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            genres = Genre.objects.all()
            print request.META.HTTP_REFERER
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            # print next
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            return render_to_response('musicapp/post_edit.html', {'form': AddTrackForm()})
    else:
        form = AddGenreForm()
    return render(request, 'musicapp/genre_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

And these are the URL routings.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^track/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^track/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^track/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^genre/$', views.genre, name='genre_list'),
    url(r'^genre/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.genre_songs, name='genre_songs'),
    url(r'^genre/new/$', views.genre_new, name='genre_new'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}" />
```

`request.path` provides the path for the **current** page, not the previous. As such, you are currently submitting a next value of the same page the form is submitted from.

`{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` provides the referring page. So why would you post the form to the previous page? It should be noted, though, that this may have a value of `None` (or the referring page may be from another domain).

I assume you have your form's action parameter and your 'next' hidden input's values switched. Otherwise, you probably have unnecessarily complex logic.

Comment: I think I misconstrued  what action attribute means. I though it just redirects to the given URL after the data is posted. Now I can see why this would not work. But with request.path I was able to redirect to the previous page successfully

Comment: Good to hear @Angersmash. If this or any other answer solved your problem, please mark as answered and upvote as you wish.

Comment: I am linking a page at two different places and I want to redirect after posting the form to two different URLs depending upon from where that form URL was clicked. I am thinking about maintaining session variables for it. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Your view could also submit the data to another url if needed or perform business logic based on the button clicked. You can tell what button is clicked if you use named input elements w/ a value attribute in your html (the value of which will show up in your request.POST) . See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129346/if-an-html-form-has-two-input-type-submit-buttons-how-do-i-know-which-got-c). 

Your form will not submit to two urls at once from the client's computer without custom Javascript. This is not common behavior for html forms.

Answer (score 1):

you have two forms and they are nested. Inner form uses GET (if nothing specified, then GET will be used per default) and outer one uses POST. this is purely chaos and you should not do so. if you fix this, I am sure the bug will also be fixed.

`{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` is not necessarily the previous page you think about. You should not use it this way. I would work with GET (e.g. with `'?prev=/url/before/form/'`) to remember which page the user is coming from.

Comment: I didn't notice that I have two form tags in the HTML. I might have missed it while copy-pasting it from my other form's html. Thanks you for correcting that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your urls.py

```
 url(r'^$', views.home, name='post_list'),
```

with

```
 url(r'^postlist/$',views.home, name='post_list'),
```

and in your form

```
<form action="{% url 'post_list' %}" role="form">
```

to be

```
<form action="/postlist" role="form" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem by comparing the URL from which we are clicking the link and then setting a hidden field depending upon the previous 
URL `(request.META.HTTP_REFERER)` and redirecting according to flag value I'm getting from the template.

This is my template

```
{% extends 'musicapp/base.html' %} {% block content %}
<!-- <h1>New post</h1> -->
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}



<div class="add_track_form" >

  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <section class="panel panel-default">
          <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Add Genre</header>
          <div class="panel-body">

                  <div class="form-group">

                      <label>Title</label>
                       {{ form.name }}
                  </div>

                  {% if 'track/new/' in request.META.HTTP_REFERER %}
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value = 0 id="flag" maxlength="50" name="flag" type="text">
                  {% else %}
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value = 1 id="flag" maxlength="50" name="flag" type="text">
                  {% endif %}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Submit</button>

          </div>
      </section>
  </div>

</div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the views function:

```
def genre_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddGenreForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            redirect_flag = request.POST.get("flag", "")  # redirect to different places depending upon where it was clicked
            post.save()
            genres = Genre.objects.all()
            print redirect_flag
            if redirect_flag == '0':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_new'))
            elif redirect_flag == '1':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('genre_list'))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        form = AddGenreForm()
    return render(request, 'musicapp/genre_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have an easier way.

Template:

```
<div hidden>
     <input name="url_get" value={{ url_ref }}>
</div>
```

View:

```
url_get = request.POST.get('url_get')
if url_get:
   url_ref = url_get
else:
   url_ref = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
args['url_ref'] = url_ref
```

So, we always have the first url

Answer (score 0):

This might look like a long time coming but applying the reasoning from Ian Prince. Please pay attention to some changes that have been made.

```html
{% extends 'musicapp/base.html' %} {% block content %}
<!-- <h1>New post</h1> -->
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}



<div class="add_track_form" >

  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <section class="panel panel-default">
          <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Add Genre</header>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="{% url 'post_list' %}" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <label>Title</label>
                       {{ form.name }}
                  </div>
                  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
      </section>
  </div>

</div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

These changes include:

```html
action='{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}'
<!-- although this was posted as: action={{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }} -->
```

and the change of:

```html
value="{{ request.path }}"
```

to:

```html
value="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}"
```

That solved my problem. I hope it solves yours