# Form submission for different buttons

Tags: php, html, forms

Good Day All,
I have a form with two buttons. One to "Edit" and the other one to "Delete" pilot records:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo adminurl('/pilotmanager/pilotsedit');?>">
<table class="PManager">
    <tr><th colspan="2">pilot edit form</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>First Name:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>         
        <td><b>Last Name:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Airline:</b></td>
        <td>
            <select name="code">
            <?php
            $allairlines = OperationsData::GetAllAirlines();
            foreach($allairlines as $airline)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$airline->code.'" '.$sel.'>'.$airline->name.'</option>';
                }
            ?>  
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Transfer Hours:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="transferhours" value="<?php echo $transferhours;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><b>Hub:</b></td>
        <td>
            <select name="hub">
            <?php
            $allhubs = OperationsData::GetAllHubs();
            foreach($allhubs as $hub)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$hub->icao.'" '.$sel.'>'.$hub->icao.' - ' . $hub->name .'</option>';
                }
            ?>  
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Total Flights:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="totalflights" value="<?php echo $totalflights;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><b>Total Pay:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="totalpay" value="<?php echo $totalpay;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><b>Pilot active:</b></td>
        <td>
        <?php 
        if(intval($pilot->retired) == 1) 
            {  
                $retsel='selected'; 
                $activesel = ''; 
            }
        else
            {
                $activesel = 'selected'; 
                $retsel = '';
            }
        ?>
            <select name="retired">
                <option value="0" <?php echo $activesel?>>Active</option>
                <option value="1" <?php echo $retsel?>>Inactive</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><b>Email Address:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="pilotid" value="<?php echo $pilotid;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="saveprofile">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deletepilot">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" style="width:200px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" style="width:200px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

In my module I have the following function:

```
public function pilotsedit() {
    $pilotid = $_POST['pilotid'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'saveprofile':
            $this->savepro($pilotid);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Profile Updated!");</script>';
            $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // right back to the referrer page from where you came.
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=' . $url . '">';
            break;
        case 'deletepilot':
            $this->deletePilot($pilotid);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Pilot Deleted!");</script>';
            $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // right back to the referrer page from where you came.
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=' . $url . '">';
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to separate the button submission using "case" statement in my module but when I submit the form using "Edit" button the record gets deleted. Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Remove the 2 hidden inputs with the same name (since that makes absolutely no sense) and put name and value on each submit button instead. Only the button used to submit will have its name/value passed on `$_GET/$_POST`

Comment: Well, you have two hidden input fields defining the same POST variable `action`. That means the second will win.

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129346/if-an-html-form-has-two-input-type-submit-buttons-how-do-i-know-which-got-c

Comment: Thanks guys. Do I still need the "case" statement?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use **button** instead of **input** tag. What I did was the folowing:

```
<td colspan="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="pilotid" value="<?php echo $pilotid;?>">
  <button type="submit"  name="action"  value="saveprofile" style="width:200px;">Save Changes</button>
  <button type="submit"  name="action"  value="deletepilot" style="width:200px;">Delete Pilot</button>
</td>
```

And in my PHP module:

```
public function pilotsedit() {
    $pilotid = $_POST['pilotid'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'saveprofile':
            $this->savepro($pilotid);
            break;
        case 'deletepilot':
            $this->deletePilot($pilotid);
            break;
    }
}
```

And it worked like I was expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You both send these actions on saveprofile and deletepilot

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="saveprofile">`

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="deletepilot">`

You should separate them.