# PHP and HTML form issue

Tags: php, html

Mycode

```
    $show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_group_options");
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($show))
    {
        $op_id = $array['op_id'];
        $group = $array['group'];
        echo "<form action = 'options.php' method = 'post'>";
        echo "$op_id <input type='hidden' name='op_id' value='$op_id'>";
        echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'group' value = '$group'>";

        echo "<input type='button' name='edit' value='edit'>";
        echo "<input type='button' name='del' value='delete'>";
        echo "</form><br>";

    }
    echo "<form action = 'options.php' method = 'post'>
          <input type = 'text' name = 'group'><br>
          <input type = 'submit' name = 'addgroup'></form>";
```

I am a PHP newbie, I want those "edit" and "delete" buttons to send a POST request to a options.php page, but with this code when I hit a button nothing happens. How can I fix this error?

The second form option is ok for now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: you need to define `onclick` action with the buttons.

Comment: is your `options.php` in the same directory with this html form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `type='button'` to `type='submit'`.

You should close input tags simply by adding a whitespace and a slash to the end. Like this:

```
<input type='text' name='username' />
```

I don't know if you want to have multiple forms or just 1. If you want 1 form, than put `<form></form>` tags outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open and close the `<form>` tag outside the while loop
2. Use `<input type='submit'>`. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form) to see how can you use two submit buttons in one form
3. And finally as [Truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/truth) mentioned above, use  PDO / MySQLi

Comment: OK. are you using `<input type='button'>` OR `<input type='submit'` inside your first form ?

Comment: it's work, I forgot to use submit instead of button.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must add some action to the button, i.e. `<input type='button' name='edit' value='edit' onClick='edit()'>`. When you click it, a javascript function `edit()` wil be called. It should  have some `AJAX` request to your php page, [`POST`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`GET`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). You can use [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add a javascript function to the button's onclick that fires a form submission, or change the button type from "button" to "submit" in order for it to post the page.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "<form action = 'options.php' method = 'post'>";
$show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_group_options");
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($show))
{
    $op_id = $array['op_id'];
    $group = $array['group'];

    echo "$op_id <input type='hidden' name='op_id' value='$op_id'>";
    echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'group' value = '$group'>";

    echo "<input type='button' name='edit' value='edit'>";
    echo "<input type='button' name='del' value='delete'>";
}
echo "</form><br>";

echo "<form action = 'options.php' method = 'post'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'group'><br>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'addgroup'></form>";
```

Try something like this.

Comment: it still won't work - there is no submit button for first form.