# Handling 2 submit buttons in one form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have read many articles explaining how to handle 2 submit buttons in a form but none of them have worked for me.

**form**:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" name="btngroup" value="remove" />
<input type="submit" name="btngroup" value="activate" />
</form>
```

**js:**

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/removeDocPermanently',
            type: 'POST',
            DataType: "html",
            data: form.serialize()
    });
});
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult removeDocPermanently(string btngroup, FormCollection form)
{  
   //btngroup does not get the value of the clicked submit button
}
```

Is this possible to get the pressed submit button in the js submit function or the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two submit buttons in one form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hold the submit object on submit button click and use it in submit funciton.

```
var submitCommand;
$('input:submit').click(function(){
 submitCommand = $(this);
});


$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
       alert(submitCommand.val());
       //your code
});
```

Comment: a bit hacky but likely the only thing to work... since js is assumed there are probably better ways than using 2 submits in the first place