# How do I detect which Form Input Type=image was pressed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post so be gentle. (I'm probably asking for trouble now!)

I have an HTML page with a form that has more than one 'image' type input for submitting. I've found out how to get a JavaScript validation function running using 'on submit' within the form declaration. But once in the java function I can't find a way to reference the image that I clicked on so I can detect which of the two it was.

Any help would appreciated.

Marc

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure of the form element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to do it on the server-side**: I suppose it's same as in case of type=submit buttons. And there is a question about [several submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form).

**If you need to do it on the client-side**: you can bind event handler (on event `onclick`) not on form, but on buttons themselves. Then you can refer to the clicked button inside handler as `this`. Alternatively (I'm not sure if it works), you can try to deal with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target) property.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like the example in the link you gave me is in PHP rather than JavaScript, sorry to be fussy. Also, I don't know if the name and value attributes are available for image input types? It certainly didn't recognise them in my function.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood you. I thought you need to recognize it on server side, since you're talking about Java (Java and JavaScript are **totally different** languages). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help B. In conjunction with your tip and looking at the related posts, I found the following code that worked a treat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicked;
function mysubmit() {
    alert(clicked);
}
</script>
<form action="" onsubmit="mysubmit();return false">
    <input type="submit" onclick="clicked='Save'" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="clicked='Add'" value="Add" />
</form>
```

I then spent a long time wondering why my if..then..else wasn't working. It turned out to be because I used a capital E in 'else'!!! It's probably because I'm using Textpad instead of a proper debugger. I've been programming in VB for decades and never had so much trouble with syntax!