# Modify and Call Custom Binding In Knockout.js Explicitly

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

Can I call the custom binding called `form` from another custom binding called `addAnother` explicitly?  Also can I modify the parameters going into the parent custom binding?

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.addAnother = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).click(function () {
                //$(element).parents('form')....
            });
        }
    };

<form class="box clearfix" action="@Request.RawUrl" data-bind="form:{ id: @Model.Division.Id }">
    @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Division", Model.Division)
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Button")
            <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-bind="addAnother: { }"><i class="icon-save icon-white"></i> Save +</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but if the binding is on another element, as in your case, it will be very brittle. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to have a multiple buttons modify a form submit binding dynamically.

Comment: Why not have the buttons call viewmodel functions to modify a viewmodel property, which is accessed by the submit function? It would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I could, I just like how clean the submit is by sending the form element in its parameter which I need.

Comment: Well, you can access an elements binding with `ko.contextFor(element)`, but to get it from the child you will need to do traversals, which are brittle by nature. This will return the binding context of the element, which you can then modify or call.