# php more than one submit button not working

Tags: php, forms, button, submit

```
    <form action="add_post.php" method="POST"> 
       <input type="text".... bla
        bla... 
      <input type= bla bla 
       <input type="reset" name="reset"    value="Reset" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
    <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="file upload"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="post form"> 
    </form>
```

**in add_post.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    echo $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
echo    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO upload set name='".$fileName."', size='".$fileSize."', type='".$fileType."', content='".$content."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
     echo "Button1 Is Set <br>";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
 echo "Button2 Is Set <br>";

}
```

But, but it gives me this output...
[image]

Comment: Can you show the html

Comment: userfile ??? well it is unable to find it... show your html

Comment: see updates... and it can identify which button hit plz help me out :):)

Comment: There's no `<input name="userfile" type="file">` in the update.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using two submit buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="add_post.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You also need to add some checks, to make sure `$_FILES` is actually set, because if it isn't then you're adding undefined indexes to variables.

Also check here: [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)