# PHP Functions for two buttons in a form and two calculations

Tags: php, forms, function

I have currently created a form with two different buttons and i would like both buttons to do a different function, the first button is the Pay on Finance button and when that is pressed i would like it to divide the value the user entered into the text box by 12 and then echo "Your monthly payment will be *result*". and then for the second button which is Pay Full Amount it would multiply the value by 0.2 and then echo "please pay the deposit of *result* and pay the rest next week"

I have attempted this myself but don't fully understand what to do to get this working, i have read up a little on functions within php but i am a beginner and not too sure what i am doing with it, any help would be most appreciated.

Here is the code of the form I currently have.

```
<div id="form">
<form action="nissan350z.php" method="post">

   <center> <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent" />
  <input type="Submit"  value="Pay on Finance"> 
  <input type="Submit"  Value="Pay Full Amount">  </center>

</form>
```

Comment: Here [link][1] is an example how to handle two submitt buttons on a form


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/547848/2596762) answer. Provides 2 ways of getting what you need.

Comment: Why does this question look familiar(?)

Comment: *"Here is the code of the form I currently have."* Is that it? Why should we write code for you? This question looks awfully familiar from about 2 weeks ago. May not be you; however you need to provide code that you tried. **We help, we don't build.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same things by using php and javascript.

Modify HTML code in your current file which you mentioned above,

```
<input type="Submit"  name="Finance" value="Pay on Finance"> 
<input type="Submit"  name="Full" Value="Pay Full Amount">
```

In your nissan350z.php file write,

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Finance'])){
  $result=str_replace(",","",$_POST['percent'])/12;
  echo $result;
  echo "Your monthly payment will be result";
} 

if (isset($_POST['Full'])){
  $result=str_replace(",","",$_POST['precent'])*0.2;
  echo $result;
  echo "please pay the deposit of result and pay the rest next week";
}
?>
```

Comment: just write echo $result; on the very next line

Comment: on here you have put /2 is that divide by 2 or divide by 0.2 because thats what i need so if it isnt how would i put that in just type .2 would that work?

Comment: okay thanks i had managed to work it out anyway xD although i have a minor quibble, if i enter 80,000 and press the finance button it displays 6.6666667 roughly, which is obviously wrong but when i enter 80000 it displays the correct number being something like 6666,6666667 is there a way i can make it so it works with a comma as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="Submit"  name="Finance" value="Pay on Finance"> 
  <input type="Submit"  name="Full" Value="Pay Full Amount">
```

Notice I have added the name attribute. then validate with

```
if (isset($_POST['Finance'])){
 //User pressed Finance
} 

if (isset($_POST['Full'])){
 // User pressed Full
}
```

Comment: the If parts, is that within the form on its own or with php tags? or on its on with php tags etc..

Comment: @Petty13579 nissan350z.php

Comment: Okay thanks for that any idea on how i would do the calculations?

Comment: @Petty13579 Yeah. I know how to do the calculations, but what have you tried? and where have you gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

Give your submit buttons a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="pay_on_finance" value="Pay On Finance">
<input type="submit" name="pay_full_amount" value="pay full amount">
```

on your nizzan350z.php you check which button is clicked by

```
if (isset($_POST['pay_on_finance'])) {
    //Do Something
} else if (isset($_POST['pay_full_amount'])) {
    // Do something else
}
```