# Two actions two submit button in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've form tag like this

```
sample name:register.php page

<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="form10.php" method="post">
<input id="pd" name="pd" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd1" name="fname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd2" name="mname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd2" name="lname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
6 more input boxes
<button name="submit" type="submit">Register</button>
<button name="preview" type="submit">Preview</button>

</form>
```

I'm sending this info to next form10.php page and displaying all the 10 input values on that page
I'm using `$pd= htmlentities($_POST['pd']);` `$fname= htmlentities($_POST['fname']);` to fetch values from form tag and such 10 variables and I'm echoing those entered value 
on form10.php file after successful submit button.

like i entered fname, mname, lname came from form tag and displayed on form10.php page.

```
first name <?echo $fname?>
```

but now problem is user can see the next page (form10.php) after entering only 10 textboxes values inside form tag.
but I want to give preview option to user so that user can preview that next page either filling any of 1 to 10 textbox values. means he has filled fname and lname but not rest of 8 fields and he clicks on preview button I want to open form10_preview.php which same as form10.php but as user has entered only fname and lname so echo only those values which he as supplied.

Now problem is how can i can have two submit button and two actions in one form?

Comment: I don't think you can't have 2 actions in a form,but it's likely to change the action attribute with js or with just php/html you could try something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form (have 2 buttons with same action, but depending on $_POST['action'] (the submit button clicked) then do a redirect to either the "final form" or the "preview form" 




*can't have 2 actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better to control form submit rules clientside. Remove the `action` from your form, and change the button type to be `button` :

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
<input id="pd" name="pd" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd1" name="fname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd2" name="mname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
<input id="pd2" name="lname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
6 more input boxes
<button id="register" type="button">Register</button>
<button id="preview" type="button">Preview</button>
</form>
```

Then let javascript control the flow of the submitting :

```
var formElem = document.getElementById('formElem'),
    btnSubmit = document.getElementById('register'),
    btnPreview = document.getElementById('preview');

function formSubmit() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'register' :
            formElem.action='post10.php';
            break;
        case 'preview' :                    
            formElem.action='preview10.php';
            break;
    }
    formElem.submit();
}

btnSubmit.onclick = formSubmit;
btnPreview.onclick = formSubmit;
```

Comment: I need to call this function i guess.. nothing is happening after posting the javscript code within script tag.

Comment: errors in the console? Place the script after your form.

Comment: see fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/y3TQz/, uncomment formElem.submit() on your own computer instead of the alert.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. More elegant, cleaner. Use this one.

Comment: @davidkonrad I created this simple html page with this code but it didn't work It's not redirecting the page http://sharetext.org/T8HA

Comment: @mr_eclair, as written above - Place the script **after** your form! :) It does not work because formElem etc is not in the dom when the script is executed, because it is above the form declaration.

Comment: @davidkonrad Worked, You've got extraordinary javascript knowledge. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the form point to its own page and handle each submit value separately. At the top of the file with the form, you'll need to start the output buffer and a session. This allows the use of header() to redirect, and storage of session variables.

```
<?php 
    ob_start(); 
    session_start();
?>
```

The form will point to itself by removing the action attribute:

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" method="post">
    <input id="pd" name="pd" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    <input id="pd1" name="fname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    <input id="pd2" name="mname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    <input id="pd2" name="lname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    6 more input boxes
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Register</button>
    <button name="preview" type="submit">Preview</button>
</form>
```

We process each of the buttons via their name in the POST array:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
        header("Location: form10.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['preview'])){
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
        header("Location: form10_preview.php");
    }
?>
```

And at the very end of the file, we flush the output buffer:

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

So, essentially the form has one action, which is to submit the values to itself. Finally, both form10.php and form10_preview.php will need session_start(); at the top of the file to access the Session variables we've created, like so:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$inputs = array("pd", "fname", "mname", "lname", etc...);

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo $_SESSION[$input];
}

?>
```

Comment: The php code for post array will be on same page where my form tag is right?

Comment: Yes, same page.  I do need to add one more thing, which is to get the $_POST data to the redirected page. That's done after the if(isset()) statements to include all that data when we redirect. I'm adding code now.