# value is not set after the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I m trying to insert user's check in value into db. For this i call the function and set the hidden field's value and than trying to submit the form but here after the form is submiteed hiden field's value is reset .

HTML Code

```
<form name="checkinout" action="logindetails.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="checkinout">
<table class="login-detaills" width="100%"><thead><th></th><th>Check In</th><th>Check Out</th><th>Hours</th></thead>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="button"  onClick="call()" value="checkin"></button></td><td><input type="button" id="logout" onclick="call2();" value="Check Out" ></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="checkin" name="checkin"></td><td><input type="hidden" id="checkout" name="checkout"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function call(){
$('#checkin').val("checkin");
$('#checkinout').submit();
}
function call2(){
$('#checkout').val("checkout"); 
$('#checkinout').submit();
}
```

PHP CODE

```
 if(isset($_POST['checkinout']) ){
    if(isset($_POST['checkin']) && $_POST['checkin']=='checkin'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attend (loginout,log_type,fk_userid) VALUES ('".TODAY_DATETIME."','I','".$_SEESION['user_id']."')";     
}elseif(isset($_POST['checkout']) && $_POST['checkout']=='checkout'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attend (loginout,log_type,fk_userid) VALUES ('".TODAY_DATETIME."','O','".$_SEESION['user_id']."')";     

}   
$stmt = $class->dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

first of all its not satisfied this if(isset($_POST['checkinout'])

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in your browser's developer tools? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: call() function sould look like this: `function call(){
$('#checkin').val("checkin");
$('#checkinout').submit();
}`

Comment: add name attributes to your inputs so you can get them with _POST

Comment: you should consider removing the hidden inputs and use two submit buttons with your form take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="hidden" id="checkout">` has no `name` attribute, so even if you give it a value, it won't be a successful control and won't be submitted.

If you want `$_POST['checkout']` to be populated, you need an element with `name="checkout"`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `name` attribute defined in you code ..For using `$_POST['checkout']` you must have `<input type="hidden" id="checkout" name="checkout">`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're checking if the post value `$_POST['checkinout']` is set, but I dont see that form control anywhere.  The only controls I see are these:

```
<input type="button"  onClick="call()" value="checkin"></button>
<input type="button" id="logout" onclick="call2();" value="Check Out" >

<input type="hidden" id="checkin" >
<input type="hidden" id="checkout">
```

Like @Quentin said, they don't have a *name* attribute so they won't show up in the `$_POST` array after submission in any event, so that's another thing you must fix.

I think you're most likely assuming that, since the form id is `checkinout`, that the index `$_POST['checkinout']` will be set upon form submission.  This is not the case; only form controls (inputs, selects, checkboxes, buttons, etc.) will populate data inside of `$_POST` and the key inside of the `$_POST` array will be set equal to the value of the name attribute of the form control.

Answer (score 0):

you really should consider using two submit button with your from, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form), and remove the hidden input and all the unnecessary js code