# HTML form submit button does not write in $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post, submit

I want a form with 4 submit buttons. Once any of them is pressed, they shell call the same page with different content. To determine which content it is, I will write a PHP Script, but I have not come that far yet. My Problem on the way is, that I need to pass the value along.

I found an answer to my question in here ( [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form) ). I copied and adjusted the code but it is not working.
When I want to access the $_POST array with my defined name, it says it is an unknown index. This is my relevant code so far.

```
<div>
    <form action="nutzerverwaltung.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" class="nv_select" name="nv_select" value="Nutzer hinzufuegen" />
        <input type="submit" class="nv_select" name="nv_select" value="Nutzer loeschen" />
        <input type="submit" class="nv_select" name="nv_select" value="Nutzer bearbeiten" />
        <input type="submit" class="nv_select" name="nv_select" value="Alle Nutzer anzeigen" />
    </form>
    <br />
</div>

<?php if ($_POST["nv_select"] == "Nutzer hinzufuegen") echo "Hallo"; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong??

John

Comment: I think your name attributes need to be different and not the same

Comment: This is a typo question, considered off-topic by Stack's standards.

Comment: Your problem is due to a typo that can be detected with the use of a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: If I knew it was a stupid typo before I would not have needed to ask. But thanks for those who helped detect it. Sometimes I just overread them many times...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to write name **=** "nv_select". You forget equal. Of course name atributes should be different nv_select1, nv_select2 etc.

Comment: *"Maybe you want to write name = "nv_select""* - Not "maybe", but **must**

Comment: ok, this is somehow amberressing. But thanks, that solved it :D 30 min wasted -.-

Answer (score 1):

with input type="button" instead of "submit" you should be able to achieve the desired result.

regards,
Max