# Several submit buttons in a single HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, onsubmit

I'll cut to the chase. I wish to have two separate buttons that does two unique functions. However, acquiring data from the same form. The current problem that I'm facing is `onSubmit()` will always be executed with whatever buttons I attach to the form instead of its own function.

`checkUser.js`: Acquires username from the input field and tries to match it with the database (Oracle)

### Update 1:

I have changed them accordingly. However, pressing `Check` still forwards me to `StaffRegAuth.jsp` instead of executing `checkUser` and then opening a new window.

```html
<form action="StaffRegAuth.jsp" name="form" method="post">
  ...
  <button onClick="return validStaffReg();">Register</button>
  <button onclick="return checkUser()">Check</button>
  </form>
```

### Update 2:

Updated my checkUser.js as it seems to be the problem

### StaffReg.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Staff Registration</title>
  <%-- Javascript --%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/validStaffReg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/preventSpace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/checkUser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <%response.addHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache"); response.addHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache"); response.addHeader( "Expires", "0"); %>
    <h1 align="center"> Account Registration: </h1>
    <form action="StaffRegAuth.jsp" name="form" method="post">
      <div align="center">
        <table style="width = 30%">
          <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="username" onKeyDown="preventSpace(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" onKeyDown="preventSpace(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>User Group:</td>
            <td>
              <select name="userGroup">
                <option value="1">Administrator
                  </optin>
                  <option value="2">Clerk
                    </optin>
                    <option value="3">Operations
                      </optin>
                      <option value="4">Sales
                        </optin>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button onClick="return validStaffReg(form)">Register</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button onClick="return checkUser(form)">Check</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

### validStaffReg.js

```js
// JavaScript Document
function validStaffReg(form) {
  if (document.form.password.value == "" && document.form.username.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a Password and Login ID.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.form.username.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a Login ID.");
    document.form.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.form.password.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a Password.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

### checkUser.js

```js
function checkUser(form) {

  if (document.form.username.value != "" || document.form.username.value != null) {
    var myWindow = window.open("checkUser.jsp", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
    document.form.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use submit.

I.e., don’t use `<input type="submit">`.

Instead, make two separate buttons and call different functions onclick. Mind you that you can still get the form values.

I.e.,

```
<button onclick="return reqfunc()">
```

Use `return`, and now you can use the function. If you want to return to the form back without going to the next page then just `return false` in the JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm still having troubles loading `checkUser()`. Does the problem got to do with the javascript itself? Thanks a lot!

Comment: there must be something wrong in the javascript. What are the errors that you see in console log?

Comment: No errors are shown. My intention is to use `checkUser` and `validStaffReg` to check for whatever specified conditions before allowing it to progress to the next page for data storing

Comment: use `onclick="return checkUser()"` . and if your conditions do not satisfy and you want to return to form before going to next page, just `return false` in the javascript.

Comment: I've updated my `checkUser.js` already. However, returning a false value doesn't stop the web page from going to `StaffRegAuth.jsp`

Comment: that depends on how you program you javascript. It works for all legitimate algorithms.

Comment: Alright, I got it solved already. Turns out I forgot to rename my function's name

Answer (score 2):

Use `<button onclick='YourFunction()'>Button Text</button>`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tricks I use regularly is something like the following.

```
<form action="submit.jsp">
  <button type="submit" name="submit_form" value="1" class="hiddenSubmit">Submit</button>
  ...
  <button type="submit" name="clear_form" value="1">Clear</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit_form" value="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

By giving the buttons different names, you can have the form do whatever processing is consistent and let the server manage any button-specific processing. Of course, you can also attach event handlers to the separate buttons.

Why does it have two `[name="submit_form"]` buttons? The first one has a class that you would style to make it active yet invisible (e.g., `position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px`) so that a keyboard `<Enter>` will fire that button instead of the other `button[name="clear_form"]`.