# Why does function only work on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit data through a form and when the submit button is click I want certain images to disappear with `style.display = 'none';`. Currently, I have to click the button twice before images disappear. Is there a way to do this on first click?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/create_post/" method="POST" id="post-form">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="toprow">
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana"> Models </h4>
        <img src='{% static 'images/USAcomplete2.png' %}' class="img-responsive thumbnail" id='gbimg' >
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test" class="btn btn-default">test</button>
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test2" class="btn btn-default">test2</button>
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test3" class="btn btn-default">test3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")
    create_post();
});

function create_post() {
    console.log("create post is working!");
    $("button").click(function() {
        var cbtn = $(this);
        var btnval = cbtn.val();
        console.log(btnval);
        document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';
    });

    //$.ajax({
    //    url : "create_post/",
    //    type : "POST",
    //    data : { model : 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `<button>` executes the `submit` function for the form, you should just disappear the button on submitting of the form instead of adding the click handler in the `create_post()` method. So:

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");

    var cbtn = $("button");
    var btnval = cbtn.val();
    console.log(btnval);
    document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';

    create_post();
});

function create_post() {
    console.log("create post is working!");

    //$.ajax({
    //    url : "create_post/",
    //    type : "POST",
    //    data : { model : 
};
```

Comment: What if you have multiple buttons that are of `type=submit` but they have different values? The request seems to only preserve the first button when I process it server side. I'm using Django.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: It seems that this problem is before it even get servers side I did a `console.log()` of the button values (before the ajax request) when I click the second and third buttons and they return the value of the first button.

Comment: Hmm, even if you label each with a unique `name=""`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the code is grabbing the first button it sees as opposed to the button that is actually clicked?

Comment: What you could do at this point is make a separate form for each submit button. Not exactly the best solution, but it'll work for now.

Comment: That's a possibility but I have more buttons that what I have shown here so it's not really a great solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80930/discussion-between-roscioli-and-wxcoder).

Answer (score 1):

Move the button click handler outside your create_post function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")
        create_post();
    });

    function create_post() {
        console.log("create post is working!");
        var cbtn = $("button");
        var btnval = cbtn.val();
        console.log(btnval);
        document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';

        //$.ajax({
        //    url : "create_post/",
        //    type : "POST",
        //    data : { model : 
    };
});
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. I'm looking for this behavior only when a submission is made to the form, so not all buttons on the page are affected.

Comment: Edited, remove the click handler and move the code inside the create post function.