# jQuery button click registering previous clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple buttons that submit to it that differ by `value`. After I click a button, and then click a second button, the function operates on them both instead of just the second button. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

This is somewhat related to a question I asked here: [Why does function only work on second click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919639/why-does-function-only-work-on-second-click) but the solution isn't valid if there a multiple buttons as it just registers the first button from the list of buttons.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':button').click(function (){
        var myval = $(this).attr("value");


        $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("form submitted!");
            console.log(myval);
            //var cbtn = $("button");
            //var btnval = cbtn.val();
            //console.log(cbtn);
            document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('rgimg').style.display = 'none';
            create_post(myval);

        });

    });


    function create_post(btnval) {
        console.log("create post is working!");
        $.ajax({
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/create_post/" method="POST" id="post-form">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="toprow">
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana"> Models </h4>
        <img src='{% static 'images/USAcomplete2.png' %}' class="img-responsive thumbnail" id='gbimg' >
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test" class="btn btn-default">test</button>
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test2" class="btn btn-default">test2</button>
            <button type="submit" name="model" value="test3" class="btn btn-default">test3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have a submit handler inside click handler? A single `submit` handler would suffice; as you already have `button type="submit"`

Comment: @ShaunakD When I just use the submit handler it returns a list of all the buttons, not the one I clicked. See the second paragraph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to get which button was clicked upon form submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission)

Comment: @LShetty That solution did in fact work. I didn't implement the second function when I tried it which was key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the form from submitting before the user clicks the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event, myval) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!");
        console.log(myval);
        //var cbtn = $("button");
        //var btnval = cbtn.val();
        //console.log(cbtn);
        document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('rgimg').style.display = 'none';
        create_post(myval);
    });
    $(':button').click(function (){
        var myval = $(this).attr("value");
        $('#post-form').trigger('submit', myval);

    });
```

## Update

Sorry, I think this code should work. The above code would run twice, since a button click would be considered a form submit as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $(':button').click(function (){
        var myval = $(this).attr("value");
        console.log("form submitted!");
        console.log(myval);
        //var cbtn = $("button");
        //var btnval = cbtn.val();
        //console.log(cbtn);
        document.getElementById('gbimg').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('rgimg').style.display = 'none';
        create_post(myval);

    });
```

Comment: This returns the button value and `none` when clicking the buttons.

Comment: When you say returns, do you mean `console.log()` puts the buttons value? Or the `create_post()` function returns the value? And how does it return none? As a string, or do you mean `undefined`?

Comment: From what I remember (i've changed the code since), the console.log() output my value would first return the button value and a second value of `None`. Your updated answer works.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are binding the submit event to `#post-form` a second time when a second button is clicked, as the binding happens inside the button clicking event callback.

The best way to prevent this is to move this

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
            ...
});
```

outside of your button click event.