# Distinguish among submit buttons on HTML form with two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, submit, preview

I'm using a form to send info to a PHP page (using 'GET').

I'd like to have two buttons underneath the form: one to preview the generated page, and one to download the generated page.

I found this solution for the preview part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("form").attr('target', '_blank');
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Which works great.

To make the generated page available for download, I was generally using a normal submit button:

```
<input type="submit"
       name="submit"
       id="submit"
       onClick="myFunction()"
       value="Download Bonus Page" >
```

and on the generated PHP page, at the very top I added

```
<?php
    $filename = 'bonuspage.html';
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    // ... the rest of your file
?>
```

I'm wondering how I can combine both functions, because when I click either button, it's always the preview that opens - I can't get the download to work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)*

Answer (score 2):

You need to send an additional parameter `action` and check in your PHP handler file (the one referenced in `<form action=` ) for 2 different values (eg. 'download' & 'preview').

Given the following HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="your/handler.php" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="preview" />
    <input type="button" value="preview" id="preview"/>
    <input type="button" value="download" id="download"/>
</form>
```

You can easily create a toggle function and manually submit the form.

```
function toggleAction(e) { 
   var target = $(e.target);
   $('#action').val(target.attr('value'));
   $('#myform').submit();
}
$('#preview').on('click', toggleAction);
$('#download').on('click', toggleAction);
```

Or if you want to avoid requiring a page reload (with this approach, no need for extra hidden field):

```
function toggleAction(e) { 
   var target = $(e.target);
   $.ajax({ url: 'your/handler.php', data: { action: target.attr('value') })
    .done(function(data) {
       // process returned data (from echo statement in handler)
    });       
}
```

In your PHP file:

```
<?php if($_GET['action'] === 'preview') {
    // preview code
} else {
    // download code
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put two buttons like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(el) {
        $(el).parents('form').first().attr('target','_blank').find('input[name="what"]').val('download');
    }
</script>

<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="what" value="preview" />
    <input type="submit" value="Preview" />
    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
</form>
```

This way, you'll get an additional variable named `what` indicating which button was pressed.

And in your PHP file, just do:

```
<?php
$filename = '/complete/path/of/the/file.html';
if($_GET['what'] === 'preview') {
    //
} else {
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
    header('Content-type: text/html');
}

echo file_get_contents($filename);

?>
```

There is another method, with two submit buttons with names and different values and you can test that in your PHP script, but you still need to use Javascript for `target="_blank"` for download.

A nicer approach is with HTML5 `<a download>` syntax. Check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).