# How to get Double Buttons to "fire" in Bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-submit, cancel-button

I have a Bootstrap form with Double Buttons (2) as shown below.

- The `submit button` fires and returns processing to the page (i.e., ['PHP_SELF'])
- However, the `cancel button` does nothing

How can I get both buttons to fire and return processing to the page?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>

<legend>My Form<</legend>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" type="submit">Update Profile</button>
    <button id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-default" value="0" type="submit">Cancel Update</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

**Appended (per threaded comment from @Fred):**
added `type="submit"` to both buttons but that did not make it work.
***This is the answer -- it works when you add `type="submit"`***

**Appended:**
here is my server-side code which has been my proof that cancel button does nothing -- didn't think I needed to prove why the cancel button did not work -- was just thinking than an experienced Bootstrap developer would have know right off the bat what was missing:

```
<?php
//This is Server-Side
  if( $_POST['cancel'] ) {
    echo 'cancel button pressed';
  }
  elseif( $_POST['submit'] ) {
    echo 'submit button pressed';
  }
?>
```

Comment: *"However, the cancel button does nothing"* - hard to say why that is. You tagged as PHP, so you may not have the POST array set for it. You also don't have types for your buttons.

Comment: "Ajax is an option" true @Fred but I am not ready to go down that path with this form. Plus I am just looking for a fundamental explanation as to why both buttons do not work as I begin to learn and code in Bootstrap.

Comment: look at my other/2nd comment.

Comment: There's no functionality in bootstrap. LOL. It is either jquery or javascript.

Comment: added ` type="submit"` but that did not make it work

Comment: if your PHP doesn't have `$var=$_POST['cancel'];` then that's why it's failing. Check for errors, check your console if you're using JS that you're not showing, including the PHP I asked for. I can't help you any further.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding at @aldrin27 but is your LOLL directed at me or Bootstrap? Again, I am beginning to learn the framework so the subtle remark goes over my head at this juncture.

Comment: you probably got that downvote because of missing information. You've given the community an HTML form and nothing else. and please don't shout,that doesn't help you here. I for one tried to help you but you're not helping us here.

Comment: The HUGEST problem with this service is downvotes do not require explanations. So unproductive and discouraging to want to come here to post and learn.

Comment: again; post your PHP or check for errors with error reporting. Your question is unclear. again... if you're using JS, check your console and/or post it in your question. Again... I for one can't help you if I/we don't know what the PHP is and if the problem is in there or not. Why are you adament on not posting the PHP and probable JS?

Comment: added the PHP as an addendum

Comment: The answer is the `<button>` tag needs a `type="submit"` in order to work on _my server_. If you post that as an answer @Fred, then I'll select it. Thank you very much for helping learn this requirement for Bootstrap. Greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I posted something 15 minutes ago but no response. I made a few edits since then, therefore you will need to reload my answer. If that does nothing to solve this, do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The problem here is that you're using everything on the same page, HTML form and PHP.</strike>

The reason why it's failing is because you need to use `isset()` for both of your POST arrays.

```
<?php
//This is Server-Side
  if(isset($_POST['cancel'] )) {
    echo 'cancel button pressed';
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit'] )) {
    echo 'submit button pressed';
  }
?>
```

Error reporting would have helped you here.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

- Use a `type="submit"` for your buttons.

This answer is based on what you posted with the HTML form and PHP. If Javascript is used here, then that is the type of "firing" mechanism needed.

If you want to return to the processing page, you can use a header to redirect or a meta refresh or a JS solution.

Consult the following on Stack on doing a redirect:

- [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

---

Another option would be to give both your buttons the same name attribute, and doing:

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Update Profile" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel Update" />
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update Profile') {
    //action for update here
} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Cancel Update') {
    //action for delete
} else {
    //invalid action!
}
```

The above was borrowed from this answer on Stack https://stackoverflow.com/a/547848/

You can replace the input types as buttons and using `<button type="submit" ...>`

Comment: You are correct on the "another option" @Fred. That will work as well as adding `type="submit"` to the `<button>` tag. Selected this as the answer - moving on now...

Comment: @H.Ferrence Yeah, it's always nice to have more options and knowing about them. Sometimes that makes a difference and especially if Javascript is used. Many times, a button type is what is needed in JS. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You have basic problem with HTML and PHP knowledge, and not with bootstrap.

Search SO before you post: [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: "You have basic problem with HTML and PHP knowledge" :) @Izzy ;) been coding in PHP since late '90's