# PHP site to control Arduino sends code on load of webpage

Tags: php, arduino

I am trying to create a domotica setup with my Arduino and my server. Before using the RF transmitter, I'm trying to control LEDs (setting them on/off) from my php webpage.

It all works perfectly, except for the fact that LED1 turns on when I'm loading/refreshing the webpage. My webpage contains the following code (which I adapted from https://www.lassiemarlowe.com/tutorials/power-led-bulbs-arduino-php-part-2/):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Arduino Domotica Control Panel</title>
```

Some css code here...

```
<?php
switch($_POST)
{
    case isset($_POST['submitOn']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 1);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['submitOff']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 2);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['submitOn1']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 3);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['submitOff1']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 4);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['submitOn2']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 5);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['submitOff2']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 6);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['allon']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 7);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case isset($_POST['alloff']):
        $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
        fwrite($fp, 8);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
}

?>
</head>


<body>

<h1>Control Panel</h1>


<form class="control-panel-frm" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d turnOn" name='submitOn' value='LED 1 on'>
    <input type='submit' class="s3d switchoff" name='submitOff' value='LED 1 off'>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d turnOn" name='submitOn1'  value='LED 2 on'>
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d switchoff"  name='submitOff1' value='LED 2 off'>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d turnOn" name='submitOn2'  value='LED 3 on'>
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d switchoff"  name='submitOff2'  value='LED 3 off'>
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' class="s3d turnOn"  name='allon' value='All LEDs on'>
    <input type='submit'  class="s3d switchoff"  name='alloff' value='All LEDs off'>

</form>
```

As stated before, the problem is that LED1 (corresponding to php post 'submitOn') turns on when I load/refresh the webpage. When checking the serial monitor, the Arduino receives a '1'.

*What should I change in order to prevent my webpage from sending anything to the Arduino when it loads?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understood switch wrong. Switch compares the value from the braces `()` with the value given by case. See the manual page for [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to get more clarification on this.

Besides that you did not unterstood the transfer of data from a html form to a PHP application. You send `LED 1 on` as value for the form element `submitOn`.

Try this:

```
<?php
$actions = [
    'submitOn' => 1,
    'submitOff' => 2, 
    //...
];

if(!empty($_POST['action']) && array_key_exists($_POST['action'], $actions)){
    $fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB1", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $actions[$_POST['action']]);
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
<form class="control-panel-frm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" class="s3d turnOn" name="action" value="submitOn">
    <input type="submit" class="s3d switchoff" name="action" value="submitOff">
</form>
```

Note that an empty `action` of a form sends the form data to the current page. See [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form) for the use of more than one submit button.

Comment: There is one syntax error in the `if` line of the code; the line should be ended by 3 brackets `)` instead of the two as seen in the code.