# Submitting a form using a second button to call another method

Tags: c#, forms, razor

So I have this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMailAsACompany", "Contract", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cvr" }))
       {
        <input type="hidden" value=@Model name="studentId" />
        <input type="hidden" value=@Model.Project.UserId name="companyId" />
        <input type="hidden" value=@Model.ApplicationId name="applicationId"/>
        <input type="text" name="companyCVR" placeholder="Indsæt CVR-nr." required/>
       }
```

Then at the bottom of the page I have the submit button:

```
<button form="cvr" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

I want to add a second button that would submit the same data but call another method instead of "SendMailAsACompany". Is there a way to modify the button/form to accommodate this change?

Comment: You will need javascript to manipulate the DOM to achieve this because Forms only has one action attribute.

Comment: You can use javascript to change the form action and submit. Something like Joakim's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form?rq=1

Comment: okay thanks will have a look

Comment: I don't really follow what Joakim posted. It seems that he suggests using two different forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the html form attribute dynamically with jqyery/javascript

this is your 1st button:

```
<button form="cvr" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

this is the other one which will submit the data on another action method:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="save"/>

function SubmitForm()
{
 $("#cvr").attr("action", "your controller/your new action method");
$('#cvr').submit();
}
```

I hope it would be helpful! If something is not clear here plz let me know.

Comment: If so I would need to modify it to "$("#cvr").attr("SendMailAsACompany", "SecondMethod");", correct?

Comment: yes, its html form, after submission of form the page will get reload and the form action will be reset to "SendMailAsACompany" :)

Comment: I got it to work by using " $("#cvr").attr("action", "Contract/List");" !! :)

Comment: yo man! that's it. you have to specify the full url. If this code is on your .cshtml page then your can also use $("#cvr").attr("action", '@url.Action("your action method","your controller name")');

Comment: you too bro. happy to help :)