# How can I have multiple buttons in a form in web2py Python googleappengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I would like to have more than one button in a post Form. Something Like Insert, Delete, Update... but I only can have a button in a post form...

I am using this, is this efficient?

```
def post(self):
    action = self.request.get("action")

    if action == "insert" :
        self.write("Insert")

    if action == "update" :
        self.write("update")
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of javascript you've written?

Comment: i change the javascript for this def post(self):

     action = self.request.get("action")

     if action == "insert" :

      self.write("Insert")

     if action == "update" :

      self.write("update")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two submit buttons in one form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Comment: @JeanUreña Please edit your original post to include the code.