# having two input tags in one form with different functionalities

Tags: html

hey guys can anyone help me how to code, having a 2 input element tags in one form and each tag having different functions. the answers in this source doesnt seem to work for me [This is the source that doesnt work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form/21778226#21778226)

```
PHP CODE: 
<?php
    $server="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="11587496";
    $database="business";
    $databaseConnect=mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
    $databaseFound=mysql_select_db($database, $databaseConnect);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if(isset($_POST['productName'])){ $productName = $_POST['productName']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){ $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['price'])){ $price = $_POST['price']; } 
    if(isset($_POST['sellingPrice'])){ $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice']; } 

    if($_POST['myaction']=="Add"){
    if($databaseFound){
        $SQL="INSERT INTO products(productName, quantity, price, sellingPrice) VALUES('".$productName."', '".$quantity."', '".$price."', '".$sellingPrice."')";
        $result=mysql_query($SQL);
    }
    else {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        mysql_close($databaseConnect);
        return;
    }
    }
    else if($_POST["myaction"]=="Update"){
        //code for update query goes here
    }
    else if($_POST["myaction"]=="Delete") {
        //code for delete query goes here
    }
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<form id="myform" action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <img src="pictures/defaultimage.png" class="submit mysubmit" id="mypic">
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="pictureupload" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="submit mysubmit">
                        <input id="productName" name="productName" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" required class="submit mysubmit">
                        <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" required class="submit mysubmit">
                        <input id="price" name="price" type="number" placeholder="Price" required class="submit mysubmit">
                        <input id="sellingPrice" name="sellingPrice" type="number" placeholder="Selling Price" required class="submit mysubmit">

                        <input type="submit" name="myaction" value="Add" class="submit" id="add">
                        <input type="submit" name="myaction" value="Update" class="submit" id="update">
                        <input type="submit" name="myaction" value="Delete" class="submit" id="delete">
                    </form>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: there ya go. i need to do it in php

Comment: This really is a PHP question, as from what I am gathering, you are attempting to have 3 submit buttons in your form and 3 associated form actions in your controller.  Would that be correct?

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/547848/) at linked page did not return expected result?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Comment: Can you include `php` that you tried at Question?

Comment: The answer on the linked page doesnt work.

Comment: Can you describe "doesnt work"?

Comment: you won't be able to detect which button is pressed because they all have the same name attribute. See my answer below.

Comment: the answer on my link, doesnt work in a way that when i use it, it doesnt add data to my database, when i click add.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with adding data to a database.  Your question (from what I can tell) is how to conditionally handle different submit buttons when a form is submitted.  You can't take code samples people have provided and paste them into your application and expect them to work without at least making an attempt to understand the logic.  If you need help with the backend, then you need to provide your complete code including the PHP that handles your form.

Comment: i have just located the problem. the problem is in my .js file, it prevents my phpcode to recognize which button was clicked. This is the codeblock in my js file that prevents my phpcode to detect which button was clicked: 
$("#myform").submit(function(){ return false; }); 
this is because i dont want my page to refresh or redirect to another page when querying to database. i removed the code in this comment in my js file, now my php code recognizes which button was clicked BUT it redirects the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attempting to handle the form based on which one of multiple submit buttons the user pressed, then each button needs a unique name attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="add_action" value="Add" class="submit" id="add">
<input type="submit" name="update_action" value="Update" class="submit" id="update">
<input type="submit" name="delete_action" value="Delete" class="submit" id="delete">
```

Then in your PHP, you can access it in the POST variables array:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['add_action'])) { 
    // do something... 
};
if (isset($_POST['update_action'])) { 
    // do something... 
};
if (isset($_POST['delete_action'])) { 
    // do something... 
};
?>
```

Comment: i have tried your code and still it doesnt work for me

Comment: In the newest example you pasted, you are still trying to test on post variables that have the same name.

Comment: i have just located the problem. the problem is in my .js file, it prevents my phpcode to recognize which button was clicked. This is the codeblock in my js file that prevents my phpcode to detect which button was clicked.       
 $("#myform").submit(function(){
  return false;
});

this is because i dont want my page to refresh or redirect to another page when querying to database.  i removed the code above in my js file, now my php code recognizes which button was clicked BUT it redirects the page.

Comment: use `preventDefault` in your submit handler.

Comment: do i still have to use the "return false" in my submit handler?

Comment: you don't have to, but you typically want to have a return statement in a method.

Comment: $("#myform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 }); now this the codeblock for form submit but still the php cannot recognize which button was clicked

Comment: In order to detect the submit button you have to submit the form one way or another.  Otherwise you can't access the $_POST variables.  You probably need to submit your form via ajax if you don't want to redirect.

Comment: It worked! i used preventdefault and an ajax call! tnx robert wade!!!! you're the real MVP!