# What happens if we use mulptile button tags HTML with type as submit

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing MVC application where I want to use button tags as it is the best tag as far as I know.
Can I use multiple HTML Button tags with `<button type="submit">...</button>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Answer (score 0):

If you use more than one type=submit, all send the same parent form, but you can put differents submit buttons in differentes forms in the same page.

Comment: I remember that there should be only one form tag per a HTML page

Comment: Why only one form?, we usually put different forms if it's necessary, only need open and close tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Both buttons will call submit action, example:

```
<form>
    <input required type="text">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

If u will not use any type, submit action will be called to, example:

```
<form>
    <input required type="text">
    <button>submit</button>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

If button will have type 'button' then submit action will not be called, example:

```
<form>
    <input required type="text">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button>submit</button>
    <button type="button">not</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what id we use only type="button" in the form. Will the form be submitted & action would be performed??

Comment: As this answer says, `type="submit"` causes the form to be submitted; `type="button"` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple button tags with type="submit" in a single form tag, only if you want that form is submitted after clicking on that button. And you can differ between those buttons by giving different names to them.