# How to select with submit button is chosen with this.form.submit()?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I have one `form` with two submit buttons (like in the question [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)):

```
<form action="/doit" method="post">
  <input name="commonfield1" />
  <input name="commonfield2" />
  <input type="submit" name="action1" value="Do something" />

  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
  <input type="submit" name="action2" value="Do something else" />
</form>
```

**When doing `onchange="this.form.submit()"`, which submit is used? How to select if we submit using `action1` or `action2`?**

Note: why not having two separate `form`s? Because the `commonfield1` and `commonfield2` inputs should be common to both.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: @MichaelConard, no I already read this question, it's not. By the way, you can notice I already applied the accepted answer of this question to the code given here.

Comment: Do the two submit buttons both hit the same server endpoint (the `/doit` action?). If so, what even is the point of having two buttons? I could give a solution if the buttons sent to different end points, but I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MichaelConard: yes same endpoint `/doit` but I need a way (with a parameter?) to distinguish both buttons.

Comment: Ah okay, if you're sending a custom action parameter and check which one it is on the server that makes sense.