# Form submit button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my project, I added some JavaScript to avoid users clicking the same button many times. There is one page where it fetches data from the registration page. Each data row I put add an unfriend button (disabled). Once the user clicks add, the prompt box appears to ask the user to enter a subject and click ok. After clicking ok, the unfriend button will be clickable.

Here is my problem: once clicking the add button, the prompt appears and after clicking ok, the data does not insert into the database.

If I click the unfriend button it inserts into the database. I want the data submitted whenever the user clicks the add button. I think it's because this form has two submit buttons but I don't know how to distinguish between them.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$mysqli = new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','learning_malaysia');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tutor_register INNER JOIN tutorskill ON tutor_register.register_ID = tutorskill.register_ID";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

?>
<html>
<script>
function myFunction(form){
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    if (subject != null){
        form['subject'].value = subject;
        form['btn'].disabled = false;
        form['add'].disabled = true;
        form['add'].value = "request sent";

        form['add'].submit();
        return false;
    }
    form['add'].disabled = false;
    form['btn'].disabled = true;
    form['add'].value = "Add friend";
    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
<?php

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {      
        $register_ID = $row["register_ID"];
        $username = $row['username'];
?>

<form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
  <td><input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="btn" disabled />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
      <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['sid'] ;?>/>
      <input type="submit" onclick="return myFunction(this.form);" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="add" class="btn" value="add"  />
  </td>
</form>    
<?php
    }
}
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['subject']) and $_POST['id']) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['sid'];
    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];
    $status = "yes";
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,subject,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$subject','$friend_id') ";

    if($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "yes";
        $_SESSION['friend_id'] = $friend_id;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    } else {
    }
}
?>                    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your buttons have `type="submit"` so both would submit the form. Since you have no js code to handle the `unfriend` it would simply submit the form with the values as you are experiencing.

The other button has the function `myFunction` handling the click which does return false. Do not return false. You are doing:

```
form['add'].submit();
return false;
```

in the form submit function ... both of these are not needed since the button will submit the form if `no` false is returned from that handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two input buttons that are both of type="submit". You just need to distinguish the two server side by using say the name attribute. Also, in myFunction submit the form using form.submit() and not form['add'].submit().

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

[Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)