# Form with multiple submit buttons or multiple forms

Tags: php

I have a list of articles and I put a submit button to all of them.

The fact is I can't get the good input hidden when I'm in my controller because it will take the last input.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/deleteArticle')}}">
@foreach($articles as $a)
        {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="test">
                <div class="name"><?= $a['name_a'] ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="ida" value='<?= $a['id_a'] ?>'/>
        <input type="submit" class="del" id="delA" class="cross" name="id">X</input>
    </div>
@endforeach
</form>
```

Instead of doing the trick with javascript, I thought about looping my articles and foreach of them having a form.

Is it a bad practice or should I have a single form with one submit button by article? The value of this submit button can't be "X" but only the ID of my article I want to delete, and this is bad for the display.

Comment: "The value of this submit button can't be "X" but only the ID of my article I want to delete, and this is bad for the display" -> What do you mean ?

Comment: In the code I gave if I submit I will have only the last id and not the one I'm clicking.
I can change that by putting the value of my article on the value of my submit button but the display of the button will change by it's number but I want a cross.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form).  The solution is very simple: just make sure you give each button a unique name and/or unique ID.  That's it :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I still need to put the value for the button which will erase my cross.

Comment: The multiple submit buttons with different values answer to the duplicate should work, just put the `$a['id_a']` value into the `"value"` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a separate form for each article, you don't need a hidden input, and you don't need JavaScript. Just use a button instead of an input like the other answer suggested. Any of those buttons will submit the form if they're clicked, and `$_POST['id']` will have the value of the button that was clicked.

`<button>` is different than `<input>` because it's not a self-closing tag. With an `<input>`, the value is the button text. But with a `<button>`, you can give it a value, and then put the text you want it to have between the tags.

Here's an example based on your code.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/deleteArticle')}}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   @foreach($articles as $a)
      <div class="test">
         <div class="name"><?= $a['name_a'] ?></div>
         <button type="submit" class="del cross" name="id" value='<?= $a['id_a'] ?>' >X</button>
      </div>
   @endforeach
</form>
```

Unrelated to the question, I also fixed the repeated csrf_field and merged the two classes on the button.

Answer (score 2):

Use html element button : `<button value="id_of_your_current_article">Delete article</button>`

Then do the job with simple Javascript.

Comment: If possible I don't want to use javascript

Comment: What's the problem with Javascript ? Then go for the one form per article... But that's still kinda weird