# How do I handle multiple submit buttons in a single form with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Is it possible multiple submit button without refresh in a single form and pass data to designed page through database? I have a from(section.blade.php) in which I have 3 section one for man scheduled 2nd for women scheduled and 3rd for child scheduled and only one submit button, but I want on 3 submit button on form for each section, so I could post data like for men(1), women(1+) and child(1+) on single design page. Please tell or give any relevant link or example, Many Many thanks.

Comment: Use ajax to submit forms without refreshing the page. You need to have basic javascript/jquery knowledge to use ajax. Tutorial: https://hdtuto.com/article/jquery-ajax-post-request-example-in-laravel-57

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ajax request and response?
For example . When onclick event fired on button , make a function for onclick event .

I have added a code here .

**Html**

```
<button type ="button" onclick="licenseDelete(sendIdorAnyOtherValue);">
    Click me to get value
</button>
```

**JS**

```
function LicenseDelete(Get the value) {
    var img = key;
    var d_id = $("#driv_id").val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('/vehicle/imgdestroy') }}",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
    img : img,
    d_id : d_id,
    },
    success: function(result){
    var vehicle=JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(vehicle);
    //alert(result);
    if(result){
    toggleAlert();
    }else{
    $( "Failed . Try again" ).empty();
    $("#send_id").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    }});
}
```

Comment: thanks @farooq, I have only one submit button on page and don't have more idea about ajax, can you give any example link?

Comment: And I am trying to submit the data for first form so that my page should not reload or refresh

Comment: That's why you need to use ajax. You should define the url in routes and and make a controller function to do the backend works. It will returns the output even without need to refresh the page . I prefer ajax for multiple form upload.

Comment: @user10945543 I love the design in your web page. You can use the ajax function for each forms.  I would like to prefer this link for more info : https://appdividend.com/2018/02/07/laravel-ajax-tutorial-example/                              please go through this page and try  . :)

Comment: Thanks, let me try :)

Comment: @user10945543 Thanks . Glad to help you .