# Two HTML buttons but first button is always sent

Tags: html, forms, flask-admin

For some reason I've been struggling with this, I've made all sorts of attempts and searched a bunch of answers but nothing seems to be working correctly.

Question: There are two buttons on a page that hit two separate endpoints (flask-admin), however the first button (Save button) is always submitted regardless of which button I select.  How do I prevent the first button (Save) from executing when I hit the second button (Edit)?  What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I would prefer to do this with HTML alone. If there is an answer already out there that I haven't seen I will happily delete this question -- I landed on my current implementation from this answer: [Two submit buttons in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form).  I just need a little help because I've spent a whole day on this already.  Thank you!

Edit: Please please please NO PHP. Thanks :)

```
 <h3> Backtest ID: {{ backtestID }} </h3>
 <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-1" >
         <form method="post">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
                     formaction="{{ url_for('results.save_backtest', id=backtestID) }}">Save</button>
         </form>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-1" >
         <form method="post">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" 
                     formaction="{{ url_for('results.rerun_backtest', id=backtestID) }}">Run</button>
         </form>
     </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Can we write javascript here?

Comment: instead of type submit give type button

Comment: @lost_in_magento I suppose Javascript is OK. Like, in-line javascript?  I'd prefer to use HTML alone. Is that not possible?  When it give them `type="button"` then nothing happens on the button clicks.

Comment: After changing it to button you need write a click handler and what ever you're doing in foraction you have to handle it there

Comment: Ah, so that's where the in-line javascript would come into play?  I wouldn't be opposed to that I suppose. that would go in `onClick=`?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `type="submit"` attribute. This attribute let's the form send.

```
 <h3> Backtest ID: {{ backtestID }} </h3>
 <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-1" >
         <form method="post">
             <button class="btn btn-success" 
                     formaction="{{ url_for('results.save_backtest', id=backtestID) }}">Save</button>
         </form>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-1" >
         <form method="post">
             <button class="btn btn-info" 
                     formaction="{{ url_for('results.rerun_backtest', id=backtestID) }}">Run</button>
         </form>
     </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Yes this works. Would you have any insight as to _why_ this works?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work.  Now the second button is only firing. This makes no sense.

Comment: I ended up using input tags instead of button tags and used one endpoint instead of multiple. Where the one endpoint uses conditional IF statements to find which input was submitted.