# req.body is unpopulated with data in one case and populated in another

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here is my code

```
<div class="input-box" id="form-box">

<form action="/" method="post" id="form" autocomplete="off" class="form-box" >
    <h2>Paste Everything Here</h2>
    <input type="text" name="all" id="all-input">
    <h2>OR</h2>
    
    <input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time">
    
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" placeholder="https//zoom.link">
    
    <input type="tel" minlength="10" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Phone Number" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber">
    
    
    
    <input type="submit" value="Send Later" id="send-later" class="send" name="action" formtarget="_self">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Now" id="send-now" class="send" name="action" formtarget="_blank">
</form>
</div>


<div id="list-container" class="input-box">
    <ul>
        <% if(sendList) { %>
            <% console.log(sendList) %>
        <% for(var i = 1; i < sendList.length; i++) { %>
            
          <li class="ui segment">
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="time" value= "<%= sendList[i].time %>">
                <input type="hidden" name="phonenumber" value= "<%= sendList[i].phonenumber %>">
                <input type="hidden" name="link" value= "<%= sendList[i].link %>">
            <strong><%= sendList[i].phonenumber %></strong>
            - <%= sendList[i].time %> <br>
            <!-- <%= sendList[i].link %> --> 
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="action" formtarget="_blank"> 
                <button >Delete</button>
            </form>
          </li>
        <% }; } %>
      </ul>
</div>
```

This is Index.js file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require('express-session');
// creating 24 hours from milliseconds
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

//session middleware
app.use(sessions({
secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
resave: false
}));
app.post("/" , urlencodedParser , (req , res) => {
if(req.body.action === "Send Now"){
  console.log("in send now" + req.body.phonenumber);
  console.log(req.body);
res.redirect(waMe.createFromNumberWithMessage("+91"+ req.body.phonenumber, 
"Greetings! from  support team   \n" + req.body.link + 
" \n\nAbove is the link for your free session with our expert counsellor \n\nYour session is scheduled for today at " + req.body.time));
}
if(req.body.action === "Send Later"){
  console.log(req.session.index)
  console.log(req.body);
  if(req.session.index > 0){
    req.session.index++;
    console.log("im heree")
  }
  else {
    req.session.index = 1;
    req.session.sendlist = [];
    console.log("im always here");
  }
  req.session.sendlist[req.session.index] = {time: req.body.time , link: req.body.link , phonenumber: req.body.phonenumber}
  console.log(req.session.sendlist);
 
  res.render("main" , {sendList: req.session.sendlist});
}
if(req.body.action === "Send"){
   console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect(waMe.createFromNumberWithMessage("+91"+req.body.phonenumber, 
"Greetings! from  support team   \n" + req.body.link + 
" \n\nAbove is the link for your free session with our expert counsellor \n\nYour session is scheduled for today at " + req.body.time + "\n\n It is starting soon! Join now."));
}
 });
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

I'm new to JavaScript and can't figure this out. The send now button used to work when I didn't have other submit buttons added.

As you can see, the req.body is unpopulated when I click send now and populated when I click send Later or Send Button in the `<ul> <li>` list.

Comment: document.getElementById("send-now").addEventListener("click" , () => {
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
});   issue was that I had this code in a client side .js file.. But what can be the workaround if i want to empty the fields after clicking submit

Comment: Please refer to this question:  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form)