Can one input field be used by multiple forms without JavaScript?
Lets say I have a sign in form with two inputs, one for the email and one for the password. The form would have a sign in button which submits the email and password to the server to sign the user in. However, there is also a forgot password button on the page which when clicked should submit the email to the server to perform a different action like sending the reset password link to the email. In this scenario I have one input field (the email) which needs to be used by two separate forms. Is this possible to achieve somehow without the use of JavaScript?
Currently I have tried the following but it does not submit the email in the forgot password form
<form action="/sign-in" method="post" id="signInForm">
  <input type="text" form="signInForm forgotPasswordForm">
  <input type="password">
  <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>

<form action="/forgot-password" method="post" id="forgotPasswordForm">
  <button type="submit">Forgot password?</button>
</form>


Couldn't you have just the Sign In form, and if the password is missing, treat it as a Forgot request?

Hmm that is an interesting suggestion. I think I would prefer knowing explicitly which action/button the user is pressing, if there is some way to make the button which submitted the form part of the request then I could definitely handle the rest on my server

Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/547821/535275

yes that is perfect, I'll use this for now. Thank you for your help! I'll leave the question up incase anyone how how to use one input field for multiple forms though

Not entirely sure what your back end can or cannot do, but if you need to send <inupt> value to another endpoint use the formaction attribute.

Place second <button> inside the same <form>
Add name="action" to each <button>⸸
Add value="login" to the first <button>⸸
Add value="forgot" to the second <button>⸸
Add formaction="/forgot-password" to the second <button>

If the second <button> is clicked, it will override <form action="/sign-in"> with it's formaction value of "/forgot-password". FYI, if a <button> is in a <form> it'll submit without a type attribute.
⸸Edit: Just read the comments and have added name and value attributes to each <button>. The server will get the value of either "login" or "forgot" under the key action.


<form action="/sign-in" method="post" style="width:fit-content">
  <label> 
    Username <input name="user" required>
    Password <input name="pass" type="password">
    <button name="action" value="login">Log in</button>
  </label>
  <br>
  <button name="action"` formaction="/forgot-password" style="float:right" value="forgot">
    Forgot password?
  </button>
</form>




Thank you! formaction is exactly what I needed. No need for the name and value attributes with this solution though because now I can handle the requests on separate routes without the need to check what button was clicked like before.

Great! I figured your endpoints were your main concern.
